# Remove or update point 3 from Help Center off-topic list

Tags: bug, close-reasons, help-center

> Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the
>   categories listed above:
>
> `3`. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they
>   didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow
>   question checklist.

While this is **not** a valid close reason any longer, the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I usually refer to new users who happen to ask poor questions which receive close votes or heavy downvotes - seems **outdated** or **unclear**.

Can we please either delete  the `No.3` if it no longer applies, or update/clarify it?

## UPDATE

This has been fixed. Please notify a moderator to update to status-completed.

Comment: I just came on here to post the same question. As far as I'm concerned, this text needs to be removed - it no longer applies since the closure reasons were updated. I think this should be marked a [meta-tag:bug], and it may benefit from a more specific title, e.g. "Remove point 3 from Help Center off-topic list".

Comment: @Duncan you're correct, re-tagged and updated title.

Answer (score 0):

I oppose this change.  Just because we can't close questions that don't demonstrate minimal understanding doesn't mean we shouldn't encourage users from demonstrating minimal understanding.  I often leave comments to the effect of "To help you, we need to see your code, what output you expect, and what output you actually got."  This is pretty much what point 3 asks for: "Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."

It may no longer be an enforceable rule, but it's still good advice.

Comment: It's listed as one of the off-topic reasons. Since I can't close a question as "demonstrate a minimal understanding" then it should be either **updated** or **removed** from the off-topic section. It should possibly be moved out of the off-topic area and put in a different section since it does not apply any longer.