# Breaking down "too broad"/"needs more focus" and trying to understand it

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

> **too broad**<sup>1</sup>
>
> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

<sup>1. This close reason is now called "needs more focus". Despite the new name, this Q/A is about the same problem</sup>

It's rather unclear to me what "too broad" actually means. An explanation and clarification would possibly help me and others not to abuse this close reason in the future. <sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXV60.png)</sup>

I understand the first sentence as:

> You have asked a question which is answerable but there are too many possible correct answers and it is impossible to distinguish the most correct one.

(that's rather a good "primarily opinion based" but to me, the first sentence of the original "too broad" close reason sounds exactly like this - this is why I am asking for clarification so I can understand it.

Now,

> good answers would be too long for this format

What does this even mean? Does it mean that an answer is not supposed to be "long"? How long? What are the restrictions on the length of answering? It's also unclear to me what: `for this format` actually means; what format?

Then,

> Please add details to:
>
> 1. narrow the answer set

But realistically, how can an asker possibly know "the answer set". I understand that this means: ask one thing at a time but the wording of it is quite confusing.

> 2. to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

But are you (as an asker) supposed to know or predict how someone is going to answer your question? While some questions are even answerable with a simple line of code or sentence (*not judging the question/answer quality here just the fact that they are answerable in one line*) other ones will require a throughout explanation of a concept, explanation of what is wrong, why, how to fix and why the proposed solution is "the beast".

Comment: In case no.3 is outdated, please see [this request to update it or remove it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252697/remove-point-3-from-help-center-off-topic-list)

Comment: This should be tagged with [`support`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/support).

Comment: How can this question have far more votes than the one that this is supposed to be a duplicate of? That could mean this question is a bit different, but then it shouldn't be a duplicate.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

#### All close reasons are subjective.

"Too broad", like most close reason is hard to define precisely. Especially since it's subjective (again, like most close reasons). There is no Mathematical formula that can classify "Too broad".

Here are some obvious "too broad" question titles:

- How do I write a web browser?
- How do I code in C?
- How do I send a file of data from one computer to another?
- What is the HTTP protocol and how do I use it?
- What forms of flow control are there in programming language?
- How do I code a forum in PHP?
- What's the best way to write a stack exchange clone?

Most too broad questions describe a specific problem, however it's likely one you can find a book on.

Now let's get to the text. The text is aimed at users with such a question. For example, let's take "How do I code a forum in PHP". (This applies to the other titles here just as well):

> Hi, I'm a beginner. I've been tasked with coding a web forum in PHP. I get to use whichever technologies I want and PHP5.5, I've tried looking in search engines but honestly all the resources I've found were very outdated and looked like they were unsafe (they used old APIs like `mysql_connect`)
>
> How do I code a forum in PHP?

---

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.

There are plenty of ways to write a forum in PHP, each of them would need to consider:

- The backing database - How do I pick it? Do I use an SQL database? What tables? How do I even write in SQL? How do I get SQL hosting? What about SQL injection? How do I store things safely?
- The server side code - What sort of coding style do I need? What are the security considerations each approach has? What performance characteristics am I looking for any why? How will my design choices affect the future development? How do I keep my code clean?  What's the HTTP protocol? What's a session? What's a cookie? What's even a web request?
- The client - How should I code the client side? What technologies should I use? What about usability? How do I validate passwords?

Now, unlike "opinion based" the choices here aren't arguing for or against a technology, there are just a lot of choices here (so too many possible answers) and each "branch" of that choice tree is huge. I admit that this has a degree of subjectivity, but that alone isn't why it's bad.

> Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

This is there to help *the OP*. The idea is to narrow this question down to a specific point where OP's attempt has failed. Maybe the DB and back-end are all working and he is just curious about something in the client side? Maybe he got far but is curious about a database schema issue?

The goal of that part isn't to explain what "Too broad" is, but to help the OP improve their question.

Comment: In addition to the very good example questions that you've listed here, polling questions or questions that can have several answers also fit into the "too broad" category.

Comment: My issue is with this line: "good answers would be too long for this format"  Without seeing a few answers, it may be hard to judge whether answers would be too long. You might think an answer is long, but then be surprised when an expert answers it extremely succinctly. Also, shouldn't it be up to the those answering to watch the length, rather than the person posing the question? Otherwise every question should end with "Please keep your answers not 'too long'."

Comment: Actually the image at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/159916 would be appropriate here.

Comment: jmac's excellent answer [Analogy Time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215220#215220) covers this pictographically pretty well.

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question, but it's being used as a canonical, and yet the existing answer lacks one important category of "Too Broad" answers:

## We Have to Guess Many Things

If you present a section of your existing code, but you have several variables whose types and contents we can't know, that's too broad (and also lacks a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

If you say you have searched all over the Internet and looked at hundreds of pages, but show no attempt at summarizing which ones or why they don't work for you.

If you say this is hard for you, but don't explain in any detail what's hard. Are you new with computers? Do you know how to use an editor and run code? Is it plugged in ...?

If you present code so full with bugs that we wouldn't even know where to begin explaining all the things which are wrong. (Again, reduce your code to a MCVE so we can focus on that.)

If you present code which you claim doesn't do what you want, but we can't guess what it's supposed to do without seeing representative sample input.

If you present code and a traceback which tell you exactly what's wrong (if you understand the error message) but we can't tell you anything more without seeing that input which caused the error. (Infamous example: ["not a valid UTF-8 sequence at offset 987654321"](/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors)).

Many of these cases can also be flagged as unclear; but to my mind, flagging as too broad is more helpful because it's more specific - the problem is not that you used complicated words or your logic doesn't pass muster; it's that you skimped on the details.

Comment: Since [the actual reason has been changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291819/175248), perhaps this canonical no longer applies anywhere?

Comment: @Makoto Thanks for the update. I was engaging in a discussion where this was thrown out as authoritative as recently as yesterday so very good to at least have a pointer to newer information.