# With the new "why isn't this code working" we don't have a specific enough close reason for "give me the code"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Could we get a close reason that says something like

> This question is asking for code **without any attempt being made**. Please come back with some code that you have written with the **specific problems** you are having.

I feel that "too broad" is too broad for this case. I was using insufficient information for that case.

Comment: Why doesn't Too Broad work for give me the code?

Comment: I like "too broad", like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123045/c-sharp-download-web-page-with-images-and-scripts).

Comment: @bluefeet i feel that it doesn't convey that we don't see any attempts at solving the problem.

Comment: i'd be fine with expanding the definition of too broad, it just needs a "what is too broad" answer.

Comment: @DanielA.White If they have posted a question with no code, no attempt and are expecting a solution, it seems that this fits too broad because the solution could be one of many possible answers.

Comment: is it really [too-broad](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it)?

Comment: @DanielA.White 'too broad' is even better than that.  It gets at the reason **why** we don't want them to post "give me code" questions

Comment: @bluefeet: Because then they come back and ask the same question with some wording tweaks to make it seem narrower.

Comment: I think there's some justification for saying that a question is too broad if the reader cannot tell how much the asker doesn't know. A good answer would be too long for this format, because, if we don't know what they don't know, we'd have to explain absolutely everything in order to provide a comprehensive answer. I was about to post an example, but, what d'you know, it was deleted

Answer (score 16):

We kinda had one of those for a while. The problem is, folks used it for everything from [implement this spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392649/this-is-my-java-assignment) (the intended purpose) to [very specific implementation questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999276/merge-objects-in-a-javascript-array-to-object) ([of the sort that are actually useful to others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259940/with-the-new-why-isnt-this-code-working-we-dont-have-a-specific-enough-close/259947#259947)).

When even experienced users are going back and [voting to close well-regarded programming questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627435/how-to-remove-an-element-from-a-list-by-index-in-python) with [dozens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/how-to-declare-an-array-in-java), [scores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd) even [hundreds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript) of linked questions, it becomes clear that we've inadvertently described the wrong problem.

So we debated and discussed this for a few months, and eventually came around to the idea that "give me the code" is a problem [when the problem is very large and the pieces provided by the asker are too few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211080/improving-demonstrate-a-minimal-understanding-close-reason/215220#215220). This matches up reasonably well with Too Broad:

> There are either too many possible answers, or **good answers would be too long for this format**. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

If an answer suitable to the asker's needs (spec and expressed skill level) would involve writing a *book* (or even a good-sized tutorial), then the question is Too Broad and should be closed, the asker encouraged to narrow down his question to something more specific. That doesn't necessarily make all specific questions *good*, but there are other close reasons **and downvotes** to handle other problems that may exist.

Comment: I was going to throw a similar question, I specifically liked "Lacks info to diagnose the problem" ... I don't see similar reason anymore in the box, can we decide the close reason for once and than implement rather than changing them? As I find it confusing everytime we introduce new reasons on the website...

Comment: "Unclear what you're asking" should be your go-to for any question that lacks all of the necessary information, @Mr.Alien. The rest of the reasons have been adjusted repeatedly to deal with more specific scenarios; that doesn't change the need for clear, specific questions.

Comment: Actually, the new reason has this statement *without a clear problem statement* which I feel is similar to unclear, so in a way we are repeating ourselves.. :) we also have duplicates for Superuser, the very first option in off topic, and second last option in off topic..

Answer (score 9):

We've never had a close reason for 'give me the code'.

In fact, some of the [highest rated questions on Stack Overflow are 'give me the code' questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20do%20I%20in%20JQuery%20site:stackoverflow.com).

Not enough research is a reason to *downvote*, not a reason to close.

It really comes down to scope: If it's something that's answerable in a few paragraphs and is reasonably scoped, then it can't be closed as too broad.  If, however, someone wants you to create an entire website for them, then it's too broad.

Or, [as I put it on Twitter](https://twitter.com/gortok/status/471992736800047104):

> You can't ask one question and get an entire application written for you on Stack Overflow. It is possible with 100 questions, however.

Comment: the top one for me has at least some code what they tried. the ones im talking about show no code effort at all.

Comment: @DanielA.White: There's never been a "no effort" close reason either.  Usually such questions have other problems, such as "unclear" or "too broad." If it's a perfectly understandable question that is on-topic and reasonably scoped, just answer it.

Comment: *"Not enough research is a reason to downvote, not a reason to close...."* - I think that's a bad strategy. All it does is teach people to ask and the question will be answered. There are enough uniformed people on Stack Overflow that the down votes are negated, and the OP is rewarded. Many on the site don't even bother to check for a dup of the simplest questions, like *[how to echo in a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49068194/608639)*. Senior members are some of the worse offenders. They are answering questions rather than closing as dups to gain the rep. Its a very bad strategy.