# Is the new close reason being abused?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Since [the new close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258685/2846923) was added, I've seen quite a few places where it was used on a question that was just asking for code. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24167701/2846923) [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24163560/2846923) (bad) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24167146/2846923), although I've seen places where the close reason fit even less. Those questions—and many others I didn't list—are all "Plz write teh codez for me" questions, not "How to fix error" questions. I'm not saying they shouldn't (or should) be closed, but they do not fit

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**")

Will this stop over time, as people get used to the new close reason? Do we need to do anything about it?

---

Update: The major abusing of this close reason does not appear to happen anymore.

Comment: The latter two are just 'unclear what you are asking' posts (and worthy of a downvote). The first one does imply we should help the OP figure out why the mountain of code posted is not doing what they expect it to do; I'm 50-50 on that one.

Comment: The third one is clear enough; it's clarified in the comments.  The first two are "Unclear what you are Asking." I've closed them as such.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259940/with-the-new-why-isnt-this-code-working-we-dont-have-a-specific-enough-close

Comment: Well, to be fair - I think it is. All close reasons are being abused all the time. I wonder if we can somehow learn if it is being abused _more_.

Comment: An example of a good question that was closed as "seeking debugging help": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235524/are-there-apis-to-enable-disable-bluetooth-on-windows-8-1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All close reasons are "abused" in this manner; that's the problem with trying to *enumerate badness* - there's just so much *variety* out there in the real world!

So, you see a question that needs to be closed and you pick the option that comes closest to describing the problem. And then get on with your life. It's a small problem at best.

As always, if you see a question that **shouldn't be closed at all**, then vote to re-open it.

Answer (score 16):

It appears that SE has decided to make the "insufficient information to diagnose problem" close reason *more focused on code troubleshooting.*  For questions that appear to be insufficiently specified, use "Unclear what you are asking" instead.

Comment: There are questions that are asking "why isn't $FOO working" where $FOO is not "my code", such as questions relating to tool use, which are clear enough that "unclear" doesn't really fit, but neither does the replacement reason. Essentially, while the more focused reason is helpful, it excludes "you didn't give us sufficient information about your well-defined non-code problem".