# Review audits based on poor examples

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was presented this question in a review audit:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595139/how-to-make-autogeneration-of-buttons-in-form-by-getting-values-from-database-c

That's a typical example of a question that demonstrates extreme laziness by simply asking for the code to be written. It's certainly not too broad to be answered.

But it's been closed as "too broad" so I got a "you didn't pass the audit" when clicking on "leave open".

I made the choice after reading the comments and searching Meta, where I found this:

[With the new "why isn't this code working" we don't have a specific enough close reason for "give me the code"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259940/with-the-new-why-isnt-this-code-working-we-dont-have-a-specific-enough-close)

From the answers there, it seems pretty clear that there is no good reason to close a question because it's asking for code. Instead, downvoting is appropriate (unless the question is really extremely broad). So I made a conscious decision after careful study to leave the question open and then go and downvote it.

As a result I am being accused of "not paying attention". I find this very frustrating, and highly unnecessary.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer that question you linked to you'll have to:

- design a databaseschema to hold the meta data
- Create the sqlscripts for the tables

  - *Let's hope SqlServer is the target db*
- code the datalayer
- leave out a proces layer to not confuse the OP
- come up with a *rendering engine design/approach* for winforms

  - *but where should those button go*
  - *should the labels be on the left/right/top/bottom of the button*
  - *Is the text on the button also on the label?*
- code the *rendering engine/approach*

After that I'm sure the OP would go into help vampirism to ask how to handle the click of those buttons, how to execute the sqlscript on the database and how to add textboxes and listboxes.

I would say that question is waaaay too broad, it would require more than a few paragraphs to answer.

Leave open is not the correct choice here. The audit works fine.

Comment: Code the rendering engine? What are you talking about? There is an existing way to generate buttons in WinForms. The question is how to load button labels from a database.

Comment: It is a matter of speech, I'm perfectly aware how WinForms works....

Comment: Regarding help vampirism: Yes, that's probably true. Also, to be clear, I'd have loved to close that question, because I believe these sorts of questions are a misuse of Stackoverflow. But if that is what we think, then there should be a close reason designed for that. I believe "too broad" is used here as an excuse for closing what we perceive as mere laziness.

Comment: In case of assumed laziness I tend to use the Unclear reason because that points the OP to [ask] when the questions is closed. I don't think adding a more specific close reason for laziness is  going to help boost quality... there are feature requests though that support your point-of-view.