# Closing as Too Broad

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, needs-more-focus

According this [meta posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason) the best close reason for questions, which only contain a statement that someone should do the work for them, is Too Broad.

But since Too Broad means:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Many of my Too Broad flags get disputed. And I think they get disputed because the questions itself is not too broad.

**Example** (stolen from [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274630/should-we-add-a-do-my-work-for-me-close-reason))

> Write a program that asks a user for her birthday, then displays the number of days she has been alive, the number of days till the next birthday and her current bio-rhythms. Reject birthdays that are more than 100 years ago or in the future. Blank input ends the program.

When I flag that as Too Broad, it get most time disputed since Too Broad by definition not really applies to this type of question.

I need a bit advice what should I do with such questions? Ignore? Flag as something else?

What I already do is down vote them.

Example Questions:

- [How to sort a body of text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842471/how-to-sort-a-body-of-text-in-php)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842498/ios-7-above-classic-bt-pairing-connecting-from-app
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29842230/pentaho-cde-tooltip-issue
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788459/read-certificate-from-token-in-c-sharp
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29677831/how-can-i-restore-a-database-mdf-file-without-missing-data

Comment: There's a difference between *"more than one right solution"* (which most questions naturally have) and *"too many possible interpretations to the question that too many mutually exclusive solutions could be derived from it and it would be impossible to list them all to be sure the question is adequately answered"*. – I'm honestly somewhat lost what exactly your question is.

Comment: The close dialog no longer has descriptive close reasons that indicate a problem with a Q that fit more closely to a "doesn't belong here" or "is not generally useful" reason.  They drew too many complaints.  So "too broad" tends to get picked, even if the Q isn't broad.  If you want to send a better message then you can pick the custom reason, but keep in mind that it probably won't be appreciated.

Comment: @HansPassant There is no custom close reason for <3k users. Only the *blantantly off-topic* flag reason.

Comment: @deceze your right, I remove this part. And I will update the post with the example from the other meta questions.

Comment: Thanks for the update with the concrete example, that greatly helps to focus the question.

Comment: Why would "Too broad" not be appropriate in the example? You, me and 5 others would solve that differently.

Comment: @Jeroen Pretty much any problem can be solved in many different ways. Especially in the `perl` tag. ;) That alone is a vague criterion.

Comment: Instead of downvoting, I usually SKIP these questions, because I "work" in outskirts of SO, so I value my rep... I'd love to find out which flag to use and hugely support introducing additional flagging reasons!

Comment: this tag is extremely abused. yes extremely abused. it should be removed asap. if someone doesn't know the answer or extremely lazy to type answer they just vote for close with too broad tag because too broad tag is too broad

Comment: for example what part of this question is too broad? It is asking extremely specifically and any solution given to the question is accepted : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736128/how-to-code-ward-s-method-ward-s-linkage-criteria . It is not like you can answer in 10 different ways and only 1 of them is correct

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you are doing a confusion that I had done before. *Give me the code* is not a **close** reason according to SO rules but a **downvote** one.

[Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259950/3545273) are recent mod's answers to a similar question as reference.

In short, if there are other reasons for example being actually unclear or too broad, fine, we can close for that reason, but if the only problem if that OP does not show he first tried by himself, we should just downvoted.

This other [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253890/3545273) and its comment also explain the why.

Comment: So basically more voting, less flagging?

Comment: @Sirl33tname I really like Shog9 sentences : *Downvoting takes like 2 seconds* and [closing means] *asking five trusted members to spend time reviewing and voting on it* . But I also know that downvoting costs some rep what is no longer a problem for Shog9 :-)

Comment: Downvotes on questions are free. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down so I guess the rep is not really a problem here

Comment: If no close reason really fits but the question is still terrible and should be purged from the system, then absolutely go downvote. The system will clean out old, downvoted, no-answer questions automatically. However, if the question *can* be closed, do so. No reason to have it hang around needlessly. It's a judgement call and might require some intellectualising about close reasons, yes. In the end we just want to keep good content and get rid of the obvious garbage which doesn't help anyone.

Comment: What would you do when you come across one of these question in the triage review queue where you can not down vote?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Middle-click the title to open it in another tab, then downvote? (Seriously, that's what I'd probably do. And, I suppose, if the *only* issue with the question was that the OP was too lazy, triage as "Looks OK". Although often questions like these are either dupes, or somehow off topic (or occasionally both).)

Comment: There's quite a difference between a problem dump (example shown in the question) and no effort. A problem dump is hopelessly broad and/or unclear. With no effort questions, they aren't usually hopelessly broad, but sometimes are unclear.

Comment: I disagree that downvoting is the right solution for these types of questions. When I come across questions like this, I don't just want to say that it's a poorly written question. I want to make sure that other members don't waste time trying to answer it, feeding the vampires. Closing the question accomplishes that.

Comment: this tag is extremely abused. yes extremely abused. it should be removed asap. if someone doesn't know the answer or extremely lazy to type answer they just vote for close with too broad tag because too broad tag is too broad

Answer (score 37):

> > Write a program that asks a user for her birthday, then displays the number of days she has been alive, the number of days till the next birthday and her current bio-rhythms. Reject birthdays that are more than 100 years ago or in the future. Blank input ends the program.

Close as **Unclear what you're asking.**

This is not a question and the OP doesn't pose any specific problem. This "task description" is reasonably scoped and "answerable"; but since this is a site for *programming professionals and enthusiasts*, we'd expect anyone in the target audience to be able to complete this task before breakfast. So clearly, there's some unexplained problem the OP hasn't laid out which prevents them from completing this task. They need to clearly state that problem for anyone to be able to answer it.

If the OP clarifies that they have no clue whatsoever how to write a single line of code, then it's clearly **too broad**. We cannot teach someone to program from scratch here.

You don't ask "How to fly from New York to Boston?" on [Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com). Everyone would look at you funny and ask you what your *real* question is, because clearly this can't be a serious question a pilot would pose. Whether you categorise that as *too broad* (because where do you start to answer that?) or *unclear what you're asking* (because clearly we must be missing some context here) is *primarily opinion based*.

As for the linked questions, I would indeed close none of them as *too broad*. I might close some of them for various other reasons, but not as *too broad*.

Comment: I will try this, but I have the feeling that this leads to the same end since it's really clear what the problem is.

Comment: If you encounter more concrete cases like this, bring it up here on Meta. There needs to be a consensus among mods what the close reasons mean. If there obviously is room for interpretation, we need to discuss.

Comment: @deceze I add some questions to the post.

Comment: @Sir See update. Sounds to me like the disputes where in order. Those aren't necessarily *great* questions, but they're not *too broad*.

Comment: For example the first question fits for me exactly your criterion "If the OP clarifies that they have no clue whatsoever how to write a single line of code, then it's clearly too broad." since "first make it appear as it is here" clearly indicates that he has no idea what he is doing

Comment: @deceze: Thought experiment: prepend the question with "How can I do the following?" It's pretty clear what is being asked. That's not the real problem.

Comment: @Jean *"You write the code necessary to implement this. What's your real issue in doing so?"*

Comment: @Sir To me it's just *unclear* what the issue is. The OP didn't specify that. Did he already try something and text didn't appear "as here" for some reason? What environment is he talking about to begin with? Or does he not know how to type that text? – Yes, all this probably stems from not having a clue, but the reality is that we have no real idea what the issue is he's grappling with.

Comment: ... I'd flag *that* as NAA! Because it would be a disingenuous non-answer.

Comment: @Jean I wouldn't A this to begin with, I'd C it. ;o)

Comment: When I first joined SO, I thought it would be a place where I could interact with lots of other "programming professionals". What I've discovered is that the vast majority of the questions are from newbs who have little idea what they're doing. They expect to be able to create applications by simply copying code from tutorials and filling in the gaps by getting real programmers to answer questions here.

Comment: But doesn't this have the same issue of being technically incorrect? It can be quite clear that someone is asking for how to do the entire process. It's not really unclear per se and could be disputed depending on the the individual interpretation (which is the exact issue with using Too Broad)

Comment: @Super Sometimes it's hard to recycle garbage correctly, yes. Does this partly plastic lined milk carton go into paper or plastic? I don't know. All I know is that it needs to be thrown out. Discussing nuances of trash is not something I find very productive. ;)

Answer (score 17):

It is my understanding that "give me teh codez" questions could fall under the "unclear what you're asking" banner.

> Write a program that asks a user for her birthday, then displays the number of days she has been alive, the number of days till the next birthday and her current bio-rhythms. Reject birthdays that are more than 100 years ago or in the future. Blank input ends the program.

So what part of this problem does the user not understand?

- How to receive input from the user?
- How to perform calculations based on that input (days alive, etc)?
- How to validate the user input?
- How to exit the program gracefully?

Those are 4 distinct questions that have nothing to do with each other, they should have been asked individually.

However, I personally would have flagged such a question as "too broad".

Answer (score 12):

I'd close that "Write a program..." question as **too broad**. In fact, I just voted to do so. Why?

1. There are multiple tasks to accomplish, and there are any number of ways to go about the entire combination i.e. "too many possible answers".
2. How could the question be improved? Narrow it down, isolate one specific issue the OP is having a problem with (e.g. given two dates, how do I calculate the number of days between them? or whatever).

These are two hallmarks of "too broad" questions. So as far as I'm concerned, it fits the bill. I certainly wouldn't have declined your flag on that question.

The other questions you link to are a mishmash of "unclear what you're asking", borderline "too broad", and zero-effort plain downvotable questions.