# Is it appropriate to ask this question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions

The question is as follows. I have 0 prior experience with requests, html or web scraping so I am learning everything from scratch here:

> I am trying to pass some parameters to an html form using the Python requests module. The form is contained in the following link (http://www.myvisajobs.com/Search_Visa_Sponsor.aspx?N=). Specifically I would like to change the text in the "Employer", "Work City", and "NAICS industry" boxes  and then show results for and retrieve the source HTML. 
>   Please note that this is form uses a post method, and the main link is unchanged when the user clicks on show results.
>   How do I use the Python requests module to achieve this?

Comment: It is not a question.  So no.  You describe a *task*, nobody can guess where you got stuck trying to implement it yourself.

Comment: I'm stuck on the whole thing... Still learning how to use the requests module.

Comment: SO isn't a tutorial service, you need to learn to break your problem down into small steps then solve each one; that way, if you get stuck, you can search for then provide a specific question.

Comment: I'm not looking for a tutorial. I'm more looking for pointers ...

Comment: Stack Overflow also isn't a pointer service…

Comment: "I have 0 prior experience with requests, html or web scraping" > You need a tutorial if you have 0 experience. We cannot give you hints if you have 0 experience.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that a good question requires 1) a minimal understanding of the technology, 2) a failed attempt, 3) a MCVE, i.e. boiling down the problem, and 4) a clear description of a *question*, not a *problem* (much less a *request*).

Comment: Ok. I will keep at it and come back when I have something more specific. Thanks.

Comment: @bjb568 Contrary to popular belief, we do not only accept debugging style questions, and those are the only questions that explicitly require an MCVE. Some questions may be Too Broad without code, and some questions may still be Too Broad even with code, but it is not a requirement to have code in a question if it isn't a debugging question, and often it is just noise. As long as the question is appropriately scoped, it should not be closed just because it doesn't contain code. Some of the most useful questions on the site have no code at all.

Comment: I'm tired of seeing this "All questions must contain an attempt to solve the problem" crap. That limits the answers to only work within the code provided, which is usually not useful. If a user asks how to do something, and it is a reasonably scoped question, answer the damn question.

Comment: @TinyGiant Debugging questions aren't the *only* type of question, but they constitute the majority of questions.

Comment: @bjb that's debatable, but going around telling new users that those are the only types of questions we accept is not useful.

Comment: @Tiny From new users, questions *not* about debugging are outright rare. I think you're being overly pedantic about this. If you look at [the best questions of last year](//stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20created%3a2015..), they're almost all about debugging or "why?" questions with an MVCE. Sure, there are some general-referencey short questions, but good luck being successful with that as a new user. If you compare that list with [new bad questions](//stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20votes%3a..-2), you'll notice good questions tend to be very focused and specific.

Comment: Well I would love to see some statistics to back up your assertion, however, even if that is true that still doesn't mean that we should be telling users those are the only type of questions we accept @bjb568

Comment: @Tiny There is no way to tell how broad a question is or what it's about without manually classifying it, so I don't have statistics. My comment gave advice for how to ask a good debugging question since the context is a debugging question. Not once did I claim that all questions have to be debugging questions, as that is patently false.

Comment: @bjb568 "*a good question requires ... 2) a failed attempt, 3) a MCVE*" You are saying that a good question requires a failed attempt and an MCVE, are you not?

Comment: @Tiny A good (debugging) question. It's implied from context.

Comment: This question is not about debugging questions, it's about "How do I start?" questions. I don't see how you can get a debugging question out of that. @bjb568

Comment: @Tiny If OP continued to learn the technology and then wanted to ask a question about it on SO, the process would be to fail, then ask a debugging question about it. My comment described a process in addition to provide a checklist for asking debugging questions.

Comment: That is again an assuming that all "good" questions (as defined by you) are debugging style questions. What is to say that the OP couldn't learn more about the technology, then ask an on-topic narrowly-scoped clear question without the need for code? But this is getting way off-topic, my point is that your original comment is misleading about the questions we accept, and if you could please be more careful and clear about the advice that you give, it would be appreciated. @bjb568

Comment: @Tiny I think that the assumption that a beginner in a technology's first questions on a debugging-centered site about the technology are going to be about debugging is reasonable. Even so, the advice I gave also applies to "why?" questions, most conceptual questions, and most "how" questions. Prove me wrong, but I don't think you can find *any* good questions asked by a beginner in a technology that don't involve code.

Comment: "Why does this do this?" is a debugging question, "How can I do this?" is not a debugging question, and as long as it is narrowly scoped clear and on-topic, it does not require code at all. Saying that this site is debugging centric is false at best, actively harmful at worst. And everyone was a beginner at some point, so there is no real way to tell if the asker of a great question was a beginner when they asked the question. Honestly, if you only ever want to answer debugging questions, that is up to you. But please don't mislead users into thinking those are the only questions we accept. @b

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Stack Overflow is about answers to questions

We aren't going to write you a tutorial, or give you pointers on how to start doing what you want to do. If you have a practical objectively answerable question, that would most definitely be on-topic.

Open ended discussions and tutorials do not fit in the Stack Overflow Q&A model. Those things may fit into other places on the internet, but they do not fit here.

"How do I start?" Is such a broad question that it could not possibly be answered in a few paragraphs, and there would be far too many possible answers. Not to mention the opinionated nature of the answers you would receive. What you're really asking here is "How would you start?" and everyone has very different approaches to "starting" a task, most of which is entirely based on opinion.

Comment: [Where to start?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308836/839601)