# Another why my flag have been declined?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, declined-flags, bounty

I've flagged this post : [Where to start, implement long-polling in Faye for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36281440/where-to-start-implement-long-polling-in-faye-for-ios), full content:

> I'm using MZFayeClient (https://github.com/m1entus/MZFayeClient) using built in WebSocket. I need to implement long-polling technique. How to do it? Where to start? There isn't information (or enough information) on how to do it or if there an Faye library with long-polling.

when the bounty just started. As there was a bounty on it I was unable to use the usual flag :

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

But I flag for moderator with the following reason:

> This question protected by a bounty should be closed since it ask us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, a *tutorial*…

The flag was declined with the standard message:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Why was my flag declined? If it's because the bounty expired the moderator would have use *helpful - The bounty has now expired* or *disputed*, wouldn't (s)/he? Or maybe this question should stay open...?

Comment: Where is the question asking for an off site resource????

Comment: *How to do it? Where to start?* ? @psubsee2003

Comment: The question *should* be closed.

Comment: @Thomas That's not an off site resource, but seems to be fit too broad. Although he does sneaking in a "is there a library", I still think too broad seems to be a better choice

Comment: @Thomas He mentions not being able to find a library, but he mainly just asks for a way to solve his issue.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I didn't claim he look for off-site resource but for a tutorial

Comment: @Thomas "off site" is the key word in that close reason. The close reason is best used when someone is asking for links to resources that are off site or recommendations on the "best". Asking someone to teach you something is better closed with too broad.

Comment: Moderators are very reluctant to close a question with a bounty.  They cannot win, somebody is going to be majorly ticked off.  Like you are right now.  Or it will be the OP who has an excellent case that his question must be on topic because it was not closed after two days of review.  They are counting on you being the more well-behaved SO user and not yell too loudly about it :)  But, clearly, the core problem is that this question *should* have been closed before it ever got to be eligible for a bounty.  That this doesn't happen enough today just stacks up more trouble, you can't win.

Comment: I can't speak for the mod that handled that flag but it looks like it got lost in the queue until the bounty had almost expired (or was expiring) and I'm afraid, not being absolutely perfect, when handling these flags (from personal experience) it's sometimes easy to overlook the timestamp that flag was raised eg: "would it have been helpful when it was raised" (helpful) vs "umm... it's only got a couple of hours left - why let mods know - the community can close it in a few hours..." (declined)

Comment: related: [Are “how would I get started?” questions too broad?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308836/839601)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I declined your flag;

> This question protected by a bounty should be closed **since it ask us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, a tutorial…**

... because, quite simply, the question is *not* asking for us to recommend a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource.

Comment: Maybe the correct reason is in the "..." there :)

Comment: So you would not have declined the flag if it had been *This question protected by a bounty should be closed*? Or are you disagreeing that the question should be closed?

Comment: @Tunaki: Yes, the question should have been closed; but not for the reason the OP asked for. So if the OP had flagged the question as *This question protected by a bounty should be closed?*, then I would have marked the flag as helpful.

Comment: To me, asking "*How to do it?*" is asking for a tutorial. Maybe my english is not perfect enough to understand the full difference, but thank you anyway for the answer, I'll double check next time.

Comment: @Thomas: "How to do it?" is asking for an on-site guide/tutorial (which is on-topic unless the "it" is too-broad, or not programming related). "Can anyone link me to a guide showing how to do it?" on the other hand, is asking for an off-site resource for a tutorial, and you should close these for the reason you selected.

Answer (score 4):

I do agree that the question should be closed, but for the "too broad" reason:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

"*How to do it? Where to start?*" is just off-topic.

I voted to close for a wrong reason by mistake, hopefully other users will choose the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

No one except the moderator who declined your flag can tell you exactly why it was declined, but I see 2 possibilities.

First they felt the question isn't bad enough to warrant getting a moderator involved.  See [this answer from Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308724/250725).

> You have three options:
>
> 1. Edit the question to be on-topic. Worth doing if the question and/or answers are pretty decent, but phrased in a way that's likely to encourage further answers that are spam or otherwise unhelpful.
> 2. Flag for moderator attention and request that the bounty be revoked and the question closed. Useful if the question is awful and attracting bad answers.
> 3. Wait a week and then close it. If it's not awful and not currently attracting awful answers, then give it a week - either it'll get fixed (option #1) or it'll get awful (#2) or nothing will happen and no one will care. A shockingly large portion of the time, no one cares and the author just wasted their bounty instead of writing a better question - this is a Valuable Life Lesson you should be proud to allow someone to learn

The 3rd item on his list seems to apply since the question is comprehensible and doesn't appear to be attracting bad answer (although I can't see how many deleted posts there actually are).

The other possibility is that someone was being pedantic on the close reason.  Although the OP does sneak in a "or is there a library" into the post, the "Recommendation" close reason really doesn't apply as the OP is asking how to solve his problem, not asking can someone give me a link that will solve my problem.  Since the phrasing suggests he is looking for someone to walk him through a solution ("where to start"), the "Too Broad" close reason would be a better choice.