# Why are questions about methodology unwelcome on SE?

Tags: discussion, questions

I find quite a lot of questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903300/how-to-i-have-text-partially-overlay-my-image) where the user is asking about `how to` do something without showing any code. Basically the user is asking about **how to do** something. He is not asking other people to do it for him.

I myself had to do this kind of question once : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37291623/how-to-make-my-own-select) and basically my question was `what is the methodology to do something like this`. I could show some search traces about a solution that *could not work*. In this context I got lucky and the searches I did were enough for people to trust me I tried. But even if I searched for hours on SE before posting my question, I got myself this kind of comments :

> plenty of documentation on the net for you

Now what is the solution for people that needs a tip to find the correct way of doing something ? In my example, an answer like "use JS to make your divs look like they are a select" would have been enough to help me going threw the problem.

I often see these questions commented like :

> Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research.

And I totally agree with this. But sometimes the question is simply not about getting some code or being a code vampire. Sometimes it is just about helping to find a methodology the user could use to find himself the solution of his problem.

Why are these questions not welcome when the user obviously searched solutions on SE before and could not get any (or worse, did not know what words to type to find the solution on a SE. That makes people who knows what words to type think the user did not do any search). What are these people supposed to do, not to be downvoted to hell and to get an answer to their question ?

Comment: The first question you link asks how to overlay text on an image. Now, granted, if this was a unique problem to which no known solution existed, one could argue that a "I don't know how to do this, or even how to approach it" might be fair enough. But a simple Google using the terms the author of that question uses, at the very least gives you some pointers. Say you try some of them, but those don't really work for you. Then, and only then, you may have an appropriate question. "This is what I want to achieve, this is what my research gives, and this is how it falls short of what I want".

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but I see a bit of overlap with [Are “how would I get started?” questions too broad?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308745/424903)

Comment: @Bart i admit that i chose the first example quite quickly. I asked myself the question and had some examples in mind but did not find one right at the moment of posting.

Comment: @Gimby Thank's for the link. So if i follow the instruction on the accepted answer, in my case ( 2nd link ) i should have asked my question on the chat  to know where i was going ? If so, I understand how it's done and surely will use the chat more in future. This should maybe be clarified in "what to ask" section.

Comment: @Relisora simple how-to questions can indeed work on chat. But to be honest, you having to ask a how-to is the site failing to be of use. The answer is most likely already there in its many questions and answers that are simply asked in a more specific way rather than a generic "how to". With some search variations you *should* be able to come up with stuff.

Comment: If you have a problem at the keyboard, then SO can help you.  If you're trying to design a solution on a whiteboard, then programmers is your place.  If you don't know where to find erasable markers, SE is not for you.

Comment: Stack Overflow, and indeed the Stack Exchange network as a whole, were not meant to replicate the entire internet. Nor is any question about programming going to be okay here. This is not a failing of the site as @Gimby seems to suggest, but rather a failing of search engines. You should be able to enter in a "how to" question into a search engine and receive good pointers to tutorials, blog posts, etc., that will help you on your way. The fact that SO doesn't have those is by design.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I said a failing of the site to *be of use*, not a failing of the site. The failing part is with the user in my version of the story - to not even try to access the vast store of answers by perhaps phrasing the question differently. But in the end we're talking about the same thing - you should be able to find out without having to go to chat, no matter where and how you search. Chat should be a last resort.

Comment: @Gimby Oh, okay. I misread, thanks for the clarification and apologies for the mistake.