# Good arguments for "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

I came across [Information on how to build a web service (frontend)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429383/information-on-how-to-build-a-web-service-frontend)  some days ago. I quickly close/down-voted for "too broad".

I tried to explain to the OP on my thinking; but it seems that I couldn't find the right words.

My question here:

- was my assessment correct?
- would there have been more appropriate explanations to convey the policies of this site?

And just in case something bad happens to that question; quoting it for reference:

> I want to build my own web service that contains a RESTful API. I have an idea for a project but have no clue on where to start!
>
> Basically my project would be where users go to my site, they would register and then be able to manage their account and use the features of the service. It would be something like Netflix, LastPass, LinkedIn etc.
>
> Where or what would be a good place to start this type of project? What architecture is good, or tech to use?
>
> I have also found an answer here that is helpful in my search but I require more basic understanding.
>
> From my end I have started programming the backend in Java, I have a tomcat server running and the information is being stored in a mysql db via hibernate. Thanks to the answer in the link given I am more familiar with how to setup the RESTful API.
>
> What I am most curious about now is how to design the front end and get that talking to the backend. I have only ever had backend experience. I'd imagine html, css will be used but is javascript required or can I code in Java?
>
> I don't want to make this question too broad as many users get sandy about it but I am new to frontend work and this may seem trivial to some, but it is a completely new area to me

Comment: don't comment if you don't have clarification to provide/ask for. (don't do what i do)

Comment: The user isn't even refuting that the question is Too Broad, they're just saying that they don't *care*.  Not much to do at this point.  Looking through the comments, you probably should have just walked away sooner (or not commented at all, to be honest).  Some people just don't like how SO works.  That's always going to be a reality; SO can't please everyone.

Comment: *What I am most curious about now is how to design the front end and get that talking to the backend. I have only ever had backend experience. I'd imagine html, css will be used but is javascript required or can I code in Java?* This is a mess.  I'm not cleaning up after him.  Why are you trying?

Comment: Maybe I am too convinced that good reasoning helps people to understand. I have made the experience that people that come back in a somehow respectful way listen and understand at some point. But I guess, I learned something here too.

Comment: @GhostCat The user has the close reason to provide a reasoning, the help center article that it links to, and if they really want more than that, they can easily find lots of discussions on meta on the subject.  Your comments weren't adding anything beyond what was in the close reason/help center; there wasn't any specifically tailored advice to the specific question, so it's not really adding anything other than a lightning rod for the OP to direct their complaints towards.

Comment: cross-site dupe:  [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Comment: ^^^ if you like SE.SE approach it was reposted here at MSO: [Are “how would I get started?” questions too broad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308745/839601) (quite a pity that I spent dupe vote on a less accurate target)

Comment: @gnat Got you covered.