# Could I phrase my question better?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Is there a better example on MapReduce for unstructured data then wordcounts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58330112/is-there-a-better-example-on-mapreduce-for-unstructured-data-then-wordcounts)

Could I have phrased my question better?

I want to make sure my question gets answered, but it did not fit the template because it did not have any code.  So far all I have gotten are comments, so I was wondering what I could do better.

I am also not the only person in my class who has had this question.  I also don't want to waste your guys time. If I am, or one of my classmates is, able to figure out the answer before a reply then I will probably close the question.

I am new to Stack Overflow, so any advice you have on even the basics would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, a big issue is that you mixed a reason to close your question as off-topic in your question. Searching for examples, tutorials and stuff is off-topic. And you don't even need that part in your question. You have a specific "thing" you don't understand and you outlined that in your question. That's what your question (and the title) should focus about, not the fact that you couldn't find examples to answer your question yourself. You can mention that, but a single sentence is enough there.

Comment: @Tom  My question was closed?  How can searching for tutorials be off-topic? Are we not allowed to ask how to get started on stackoverflow?

Comment: Is trying to understand "how to get started" off topic for stackoverflow?

Comment: I didn't say it was closed, only that it contains parts that could render it off-topic. And yes, looking for off-site resources is off-topic. And "how to get started" itself would be "too broad" (i.e. off-topic for a different reason). Stack Overflow is for _specific_ questions and you have a specific question (in my opinion), that is why I said your question should focus on that, not on "finding an example".

Comment: @Tom So what your saying is that I should have phrased it prehaps as, "How do I get started with Map Reduce?"

Comment: That's all fine and this is a specific question, you now just need to focus your question more on that. For example, show use the code you're working with, show us the error message you get and if possible your tries on fixing the issue (so others can see what worked for you and what didn't, to improve their answers).

Comment: No, that's not what I meant, you don't want to get started, because you started already. The issue might appear right after the start, but that still is a specific issue you can ask about, not something broad and fuzzy like "how to get started". And that specific issue should be the focus of your question (see my other comment above)

Comment: This really isn't the type of question to be asking on Stack Overflow. You can't really word it any better than you have, you just can't ask for an off-site resource. Sorry. However, you might be able to ask "How can I use MapReduce for reducing unstructured data?"

Comment: Tom and @JL2210 thank you for your replies.  I will review my post in the morning.
  I definitely think I could have phrased things better. 
Worse case, if I cannot word it better then I will delete my post. :)

Comment: See also [Are “how would I get started?” questions too broad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308745/215552)

Comment: You could ask: "what is a simple example of Map reduce that shows xx"x with some suitable xxx that you are particularly interested in. That should work.