# A "hard to answer" question is a "bad question"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436052/how-to-access-a-sqlite-file-that-is-exclusive-locked-by-other-programs

TIP: not require to reopen it, my solution for this question has lost.

> [image]

This question is seeking a "hacky" way to achieve a problem that "impossible" in a normal way. (Access a locked sqlite file)

The goal and condition of this question are not vague: how to "access" a "SQLite file" that has "exclusive locked".

Yeah, this question is hard to answer - So... no one answered it, no one comment it, someone downvote it, and ... Community bot "think" this is a "bad question", and delete it.

However, my colleague and I did find a hacky solution, and we did it- means that this problem is not unsolvable.

Did "Stack Overflow" only welcomed "simple questions"?

Or, did "Stack Overflow" hate "hacky things"?

---

Or, did "Stack Overflow" hate "joking program"?

Another my quesiton:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54501158/how-to-crop-the-part-of-the-window-outside-the-specified-area
[image]
This question target is still clear: How to "clip window bound" to "looks like a sub window for other window".

"Joking program" is a bad things?

Comment: Why somebody downvoted it… who knows. That's somewhat irrelevant. The question got vacuumed by the bot because it showed zero activity for several weeks. That's just to clean up around the site. It showed no activity probably because nobody knew a solution. … I'm not sure how to help you with this in any way…?!

Comment: Well, the comment by @deceze explain all. Now, if you have found a way to solve this _unsolvable_ problem, why don't you repost the question with your own answer?. This could be a valuable addition to our knowledge base.

Comment: You can think that this is just for complaining - I have been unable to ask questions because I have asked some "bad" and "hard to answer" questions. "bad question" is really bad. but how about "hard question"? There is a limit of number of questions for each user, So I think current questioning policy is turning the community into "People who cannot ask popular questions are not eligible to ask".

Comment: *Hard* questions *should not* lead to a question ban, they would probably simply lead to no answer. What should lead to a question ban are unclear or impossible to answer questions, and that should be self evident. Can you lay out some clearer evidence why you should fall more on one side of this than the other? Perhaps the current algorithm *does* need tweaking… hard to say without more concrete details.

Comment: I took a look at my reputation change and I can confirm that - I do have "bad question" - really bad.
But other question I think it's not too bad at all...
Sometimes I really hard to understand some downvote - maybe they don't like joking? Or just like to downvote some question?

Comment: Imo the second question is not hard, it really doens't look impossible.  It just fall under almost all close reason. No MRE, no error, too broad, unclear. The downvote button text says : "_This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful_". While no research is hard for a unclear/Tb broad question, but it's hard to claim that it's downvoted only because iit was a joke program.

Comment: "Remove Dead Question" is quite simple text, so I really don't understand why you ignore that and play the victim card instead saying your question got deleted because **Community bot "think" this is a "bad question"** just because your question is "hard".

Comment: So the 1st question was so unimportant that the OP did not want to share his solution.  The 2nd question expects SO users to waste their free time on a joke.  Clearly Roomba did an effective job.  This site would be much better off if programmers used it for questions that actually need a solution.

Comment: @xdtTransform looks many downvoter likes to think "asker don't know how to do" is a broad question. Asker have no idea, no orientation, they need guid, but many downvoter just think this just a broad question.

Comment: @Flithor and many users do not realize Stack is not made for 'I am stuck and I dunno how to start'. Stack was never intended to be that kind of help....

Comment: We are on meta, and meta already discuss close reason  here is an example  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it. , https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308745/are-how-would-i-get-started-questions-too-broad . You can search for them pasting `[too-broad]` in the searchbox

Comment: @Patrice well, now, I see. stack may used to be that kind of site, but now, it's not.

Comment: @Filthor the help center and most guidance still point to that being the fact.

Comment: @Patrice interesting, I've found a very similar question is ask same as one of my -5 and deleted question, it's asked 9 years ago
(I didn't found it before I asking that question, maybe the keywords didn't match): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977611
The early SO is obviously much friendlier than now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Allow me to introduce you to [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba). That link explains everything better than I could.

The short answer: don't take it personal. It happens to everybody. It's a site cleanup tool that deletes certain questions that fulfills certain criteria. Your question just happens to be one of those questions....