# Just wondering about this question how it can be considered as too broad

Tags: discussion, support, on-hold

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33963654/how-can-i-remove-all-zero-digits-from-an-integer-in-c) has been marked as too broad. I just don't understand the reasons behind it being at this state. I have already made two edits to improve it but I see no change in the status. I am really interested to understand what should be done to have it open, or just the rationale behind having such a question on hold.

In favor of the question [not being too broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291335/closing-as-too-broad)

Comment: We don't do programming puzzles with zero effort on the asker's side. That this one is also most likely homework doesn't help matters (although it shouldn't be a deciding factor in closing a question)

Comment: Also the help text for "too broad" seems to fit the question very well, no? `There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.`

Comment: @Pekka웃 is there a tag for that, I.e. Homework or puzzle ? also, I don't think that answers would be too long, I think it is a one liner recursive function. There are good answers in many other posts that are pages long.

Comment: The length is not the issue; I was referring to the `There are either too many possible answers` part. (Re tags, nope, there is no homework tag as that would be a Meta tag, which are generally discouraged)

Comment: Well, this is a problem.  'without transforming this to a string representation' just about kills the question as meaningful, so the poor reviewer has to find a close reason that best-matches:(

Comment: @MartinJames not transforming to string representation , restricts the number of possible answers. I.e. Makes it less broad.

Comment: What?  It's an...integer, 32 or 64 bits.  If you remove the '0's from a binary number, what are you going to replace them with?  There is only one choice, so the answer would always be -1, if signed.

Comment: The only other interpretation I can put on it involves a huge pile of arithmetic div/mod stuff that, if required, the OP should implement.

Comment: @MartinJames that is why in c++ we have templates. By the way there is std::numeric_limits::is_integer to answer you problem. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Pekka웃 please open the question and write a few of the too many that you know, I can tell that there is the SO voting system that would do the work of finding the best.

Comment: I see no reason to reopen that question. (I couldn't do that on my own anyway.)

Comment: I think that the problem here is a massive lack of knowledge of how the system is structured and how it works on the part of the OP. I would suggest reading the FAQ here on meta as well as the help center information.

Comment: @TinyGiant please see the link posted in the question , I.e. , less flagging more down voting.

Comment: @g24l I am aware of the current policies. The question in question was deleted before I got to this question. However, from observing your interactions here I believe that you could benefit quite a lot from reading the FAQ and the help center information.

Comment: @TinyGiant thank you for point ou the FAQ, I am just pointing out the facts.

Answer (score 7):

In the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) help topic it states:

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Or from the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

[image: tour page]

From the [Closed Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) help page, too broad reason:

> if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format.

Looking at the specific question you linked to, I see no problem statement, I see no code. All we get is a requirements list. What is left for us is to do the OP's [<s>home</s>work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Although you could argue that the answers can still be short  (see the wonderful answers it already got </sarcasm>) there can be a number of approaches which will all be valid, none will be wrong and voting will be based on personal preferences instead of factual validity of the answer. If the question can't have a single correct answer, the question is too broad. Voting isn't meant to be a beauty contest but a signal for future visitors about the usefulness of posts. There are simply too many things that need to be addressed/explained to the OP in each answer so they understand what they have asked.  Again a signal that closing as too broad is fine.

We used to have a close reason: [*You have no idea what you're talking about*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow) but as that one got abused and subsequently removed we rely on closing as too broad.

What we expect from that OP is showing the code they have so far, a test run with their results and an explanation where they suspect they went wrong/no longer understand the program flow.

That is the type of question we're happy to have and happy to re-open. The question you linked will not get my re-open vote. And if we all feel too broad is the wrong reason, I'll vote for unclear.

Comment: Did you notice the "or" in the statements? I think this fall at least within the "specific programming problem" . As you state the reason "you have no idea" (omg wtf how much more rude can a mod ration effort become ) has been removed because it got abused. Is "too broad" being abused as well?

Comment: The 'without transforming this to a string representation' condition effectively kills any meaning in the question.  It is not answerable.

Comment: @g24l What is the specific programming problem? Computation? Boolean logic? Input/output streaming? Loops? There is multitude of specific problems that arise from that question. I don't call that a specific problem.

Comment: @MartinJames , what about division and mod? Did you think about that?

Comment: We are just beating around the bush. Too broad seems to be used as " I don't like this".

Comment: @g24l I can't judge for others but I'm certainly not closing questions because I don't like them. Given the large number I already closed I would have been fed up by now.

Comment: By the way, you are referencing "on topic" which begs for a flag "off topic" , this got the "too broad" .

Comment: @g24l Meh, I tried to link to a help page that briefly explains what we expect from questions and that description was the best fit. My answer can also live with out it...

Comment: @Meh you are still answering about another thing, this was tagged "to broad" not "off topic"

Comment: @g24l there you go: added a screenshot from the tour with red freehand circle!

Comment: You are still answering the on topic issue, the question got the too broad. Really, help me here in putting effort to understand that they are not the same.

Comment: @g24l well, let's disagree on that. I explained why it got closed as too broad. There is nothing more I have to add.

Comment: @rene you are just explaining why it maybe off topic , because you are citing what is on topic but not what is too broad.

Comment: @g24l you keep re-iterating that point and I already told you I don't care you like to interpret the guidance differently. This has become and end-less loop now...

Comment: @rene really there is no interpretation needed, you talk about on topic.

Comment: Man, if "minimal understanding" really had been called "you have no idea what you are talking about", it probably wouldn't have been misused. But then jaydles would have said it was too mean.

Comment: @g24l: Robert Harvey on use of "Too broad" for a situation like this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/603977 Similar on Meta.SE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215722/159251

Comment: @JoshCaswell , personally prefer this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291335/closing-as-too-broad