# What is the best Triage response for give me teh codez questions?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, triage

> Note re [possible duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip): I had already commented that I can and do skip many reviews.  However 'pressing skip' can't be the complete answer to 'what should a conscientious reviewer do in situation XYZ' - that presumably just bounces the review along until someone less conscientious presses a button at random.  I'm asking what is ultimately the most helpful response in this situation by a careful reviewer.  Also, the linked question is how to *encourage* skip and focuses on problems specifically in the *edit* review queue.

In the Triage review a lot of the questions are poor, and there are a lot that can be characterized as *give me teh codez* questions - just a problem/homework question and asking how to write code for it.  No sample code is provided, or specific stumbling block

I'm unclear what is the best response *during Triage review* for this.  The accepted answers in these Meta questions about flagging-for-closure:
[What's the appropriate new/current close reason for “How do I do X?”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) and [Closing as Too Broad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291335/closing-as-too-broad/291350#291350) both state give me teh codez questions are better downvoted and not flagged;  although the second question has dissenting answers.

The options during triage are only: Looks OK / Requires Editing / Unsalvageable / skip.  It is also possible to comment on the question. It is not possible to vote, edit or answer.

To me, most of these questions look unsalvageable in practice - they are clearly never going to become good questions.  However selecting unsalvageable requires raising a mod flag.  Following the guidance above, these questions are best downvoted and **not** flagged.  But the Triage screen does not permit voting on the question.

So what is the best action to take during triage?  None of the options seem great:

"Looks OK" - clearly not.

"Requires Editing" - perhaps this is the best option in an "I think this question is rubbish, but don't see how to flag it" sort of way.  However in many cases it looks very implausible that it will ever be edited into a quality question.

"Unsalvageable" - would appear to contradict the guidance above.  I have flagged as "Too broad" or "Unclear what you are asking", and these clearly apply to some questions, but not all.

"Skip" - seems to just be passing the buck to someone else.  I've have skipped a lot of obviously bad questions because I didn't understand exactly what to do with them;  but this doesn't seem like a solution.

So what is the correct response?

Comment: I just want to say, "Skip" is always a correct response if you're not sure what else to vote. There's no shame in it, good job :-) That said, _"should be closed... > Too broad"_ is often a good fit for questions like that, but that depends on the specific question.

Comment: I'd go with either Unsalvageable for those that qualify (too broad/unclear) and Looks OK otherwise.  If you really want, you can open the question link in a new tab and downvote.  give me teh codez questions can be "OK"

Comment: @Cerbrus - I guess I skip 60%+, but presumably that just means it gets shown to someone else until _someone_ makes an actual decision.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [There is no shame in using "Skip"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Comment: That's really a duplicate?  How to encourage skip, in a different queue suffering a lot of robo-reviewing.  Sure I can skip the whole triage queue;  that doesn't seem constructive.  It also also seems unlikely that the expectation is that ALL reviewers will skip a particular question because none of the options fit

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse gnat likes closing everything on meta as a duplicate.  Don't worry about it if it doesn't actually answer your question.

Comment: you seem to assume that passing the buck is not okay. But it really is. There are over 150,000 users eligible to review in Triage queue. That's _one hundred fifty damn thousands_ users. There is no shortage in triage reviewers. Another assumption, about someone else doing wrong review, is also slippery. Review audits take care of these folks. As a _responsible_ reviewer it is actually your duty to press Skip when you can't point the finger at concrete problem in the post and say to yourself, "this post is bad (good) because of <the following reasons>"

Comment: @gnat - sure I can and do press skip often. That doesn't change the fact there must be a best practice for someone who knows how to handle the situation.  And if information about what the best practice is exists on, for example Meta, it might in an ideal world improve the quality of the reviews.

Comment: you found best practice recommendations already, in the questions you linked from the very start. It is, in brief, that you should use your discretion to decide whether the question deserves closing. Meaning in turn that if you can't find an appropriate close reason and can't see the solid reason to involve moderator (and can't say that it looks okay or edit it to make okay) then you press Skip

Comment: Maybe "skip/looks ok" should be merged into "continue" or "next"

Comment: @Trilarion it is useful to have Skip separately, because there are questions, especially in weirder languages, where I simply have no idea if they are meaningful or not.  And see gnat's responses above - skip is encouraged!  But renaming "Looks OK" to something more neutral might be a lot clearer.  Especially if it was put _after_ Unsalvageable and Requires Editing and called something like "Neither of these"

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse So "Unsalvageable", "Requires Editing", "Neither of these", "I don't know"

Comment: @Trilarion, yes something like that.  Personally I would rename "Unsalvageable" to "Vote/Flag for closure" since that's exactly what the button does and nothing else.  Some un-improvable questions can't be marked "Unsalvageable".  But it's the "Looks OK" which is most confusing.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

"Gimme the code" questions with ***no problem other than a lack of research/effort*** belong in the **Looks OK** pile to sink or swim on the front page. Triage is about filtering in buckets as quickly as possible so others can apply appropriate action. Don't clutter the close queues with questions that they have no close reason for. The lack of a close reason for "lack of effort" is *by design* as these questions can be valuable and should be handled via downvoting if they are not good questions. Don't get me wrong I was always frustrated in Triage that people weren't flagging half those questions as Unsalvageable. There is a lot of Unsalvageable but some things just don't belong in Unsalvageable.

I used to Triage review quite a bit and my understanding (based on many many meta posts) of Triage was always a quick cursory filtering into the following buckets:

> **Unsalvageable** - Has a matching close reason (debug without MCVE, unclear, too broad, spam, recommend tool, etc.). *"Gimme the code" questions often (but not always) are too broad or unclear.*
>
> **Requires Editing** - Needs grammar, code formatting, paragraph formatting, etc that can be applied ***without OP's help***. If you can make sense of it in a quick pass but it is poorly worded or constructed, put it here.
>
> **Looks OK** - Does not fit the first two. This includes some bad questions that should die by downvotes.

If the ***only problem is a lack of research/effort***, then it needs to be marked **Looks OK** because downvotes are the appropriate action for that. There is no flag reason for "lack of research/effort."

Comment: Maybe "Looks OK" could be renamed to something like "Continue" or so.

Comment: @Trilarion Perhaps. The names of all the Triage options have been debated on Meta (to little avail) because many **Unsalvageable** are not so much unsalvageable as require some OP input, **Should Be Improved** / **Requires Editing** labels don't make obvious that they are for non-OP editing, and then like you said **Looks OK** doesn't mean it shouldn't die.

Comment: If any one Triage option should be renamed I think it should be Looks OK. Mainly because the hover text is "this question doesn't seem low quality", and that is not the case for so many questions that should be sorted into Looks OK.

Comment: I agree with @MatthewCliatt; I think it's the "Looks OK" which caused me the most confusion.  In my original question, a less-enlightened me wrote: "Looks OK - clearly not", and yet that is the probably right option.  It's entirely unclear that poor questions which can neither be close-flagged nor fixed by the community should be marked "OK".  And looking back at the results of some later, it's not generally what happens to them - they either get shoe-horned into a close category or get voted "Requires Editing", probably as a middle of the road compromise.

Comment: While "give me the code" is not *strictly* a close reason, it is certainly a red flag that should make you take a closer look before making a decision. *Many* of these questions are Too Broad or Unclear. I think your answer dismisses this fact too easily.

Comment: @jpmc26 I explicitly stated that and did not dismiss it. Re-read my answer.  Some quotes: 1) "**Unsalvageable** - Has a matching close reason (debug without MCVE, unclear, too broad, spam, recommend tool, etc.)" 2) "**Looks OK** - Does not fit the first two." 3) "**_If the only problem is a lack of research/effort_**, then it needs to be marked **Looks OK**"

Comment: Perhaps "brushes over too quickly" is a more appropriate phrase. What I mean is that reading over your answer leaves one with the impression that most questions of the "gimme the code" category are fine, while this certainly isn't the case. It is not that I disagree with anything you've said; I merely think this is worth more emphasis than this answer gives.

Comment: @jpmc26 I added a sentence to the Unsalvageable paragraph and added some emphasis to the first and last paragraph. Is that better?

Comment: Yes, that's much better, and it's appreciated.

Comment: Heh, it's unfortunate that "Requires Editing" is described as being for questions "where edits by the **author or others** would result in a question that is clear and answerable" if indeed it really should only go in that bucket if it can be fixed *without the OP's help*.

Comment: @JeffBridgman Agreed. Part of problem IIRC is that the Help & Improvement queue did not exist until a couple weeks after the release of Triage. That description is probably a relic from the early days of Triage where nobody knew what was going to happen to the Requires Editing bucket. The OP isn't in the H&I queue to help so questions that require OP help historically ended up wasting that queue's time only to get thrown back to Triage and then back to H&I etc until the review system kicked it out of the loop onto the home page. (I say *historically* b/c I am not sure if anything has changed)

Answer (score 9):

Here's the way I look at it: The Triage queue is different from the Very Low Quality queue. While both are queues intended to determine the quality of posts, in Triage the question quality is judged on a specific metric: whether or not **editing**, specifically, is warranted to improve a given question.

Here's the criteria listed for each action in the triage queue:

> - **Looks OK** for questions that can be found, understood and answered as-is
> - **Requires Editing** for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable
> - **Unsalvageable** for questions that cannot or should not be answered and must therefore be removed from the site

Reading those, here's my train of thought:

First, look at the question just like you would if you came across it outside of the queue. Is there something so obviously and describably wrong with it that you think it "should not be answered" and warrants a flag? Then use **Unsalvageable**, and flag it accordingly.

If you don't think it warrants a flag, then the question should be whether you think **editing**, specifically, would fix the shortcomings of the question. In many instances of "give me code" questions, the answer is that it would not. Often, the questions aren't poorly written or formatted - they're just fundamentally the wrong question. No amount of editing is going to fix that, so while it may be a bad question, it's not bad *in the way Triage is intended to deal with*.

If a question is bad but not bad in a flaggable way, and it fits the descriptor "can be found, understood, and answered as-is", then to my eye it's appropriate to mark it **Looks OK** (specifically in the sense of **not needing editing**) and trust that it will be dealt with through other channels. Triage isn't the only tool we have to deal with sub-par questions.

Comment: While there is a certain amount of logic to this, surely the broader intent of triage is to prevent clearly bad questions from going any further?  It seems like a waste for someone who has identified a question as inappropriate to mark "Looks ok" and let others spend time on handling it later.

Comment: Triage is intended to keep a *specific subset* of bad questions from going further - questions so bad as to be flaggable, and questions in need of editing. If a question isn't one of those things, then Triage isn't the tool intended to deal with it. There are others!

Comment: When did you last find a question in the VLQQ?

Comment: @Deduplicator - just now? http://i.imgur.com/2p85Jwl.png Good point, though, that it's heavier on Answers than Questions - I should have said "both are queues intended to determine the quality of **posts**" rather than "questions". If anything, though, this proves my point -- different tools are intended for different things, no one queue needs to catch EVERY bad post.

Comment: @sphanley Hm, is that something restricted to sub-3Ks?

Comment: @Deduplicator I've never been >3k so I don't know? What's different for you? Worth mentioning, though, that that question turned out to be an audit, and besides that, I couldn't get another one to turn up. They seem very uncommon but do exist in the queue. The "Low Quality" section in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work seems to indicate that questions and answers can both be present in VLQQ.

Comment: @sphanley Oh, they never quite managed to get all the question-audits out of that queue, seems the bug is still live... Also, the MSE-post doesn't quite apply to SO, which is (still?) the only site with triage and edit-queues, and thus no questions in vlqq.

Answer (score 6):

Out of the 30 questions in the triage queue I review almost every day, more than 10 are "give me teh codez" questions. I simply just flag them as either "unclear" or "too broad".

Here is why.

There are two types of "give me teh codez" questions. One which are clear, and the other which are unclear.

Questions which ask for straightaway code like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11923571) are normally closed as "Too Broad", and sometimes also as "unclear". This is because the question is both unclear and broad. Although, I prefer the too broad option in most cases. In some cases, when the user narrows the question down to the type of code he / she wants, closing as too broad might some times be awkward, but there are such cases.

In other cases, where the question is clear, but still "give me the codez", like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11923346), should be closed as too broad. I flagged that as too broad. In cases such as this, you cannot flag it as unclear as it is clear. It is narrowing down things, but still "too broad" is the best flag option over here. "unclear" will be wrong, and has chances of being declined or disputed.

I always flag a "give me teh codez" questions, whether I find them in the triage queue, or elsewhere. This is because, downvoting the question does not mean deleting. I know that it will automatically get deleted by Roomba, but not instantly. Till then some user will post an answer to such a question, only for gaining reputation, and even if it is downvoted, it won't get deleted because there is an answer (in many cases). [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36261784/5735775) in which a user responded to a "give me the codez" question just to gain reputation.

So in short, flag a "give me the codez" question either as "unclear" or "too broad", based on the type it is.

---

Not related to the question: Many "give me the codez" questions are tricky. They show the exact output they want, and they look perfect. They even get upvoted, and most reviewers approve them.

For example:

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11923346) question is a pure "give me the codez" question. Although, it even gained two upvotes, and as soon as it gained them, it came out of the triage review queue. Till then two reviewers reviewed it, one of them being me. The other one even approved it as "Looks OK".
- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11923124) question is asking for code in an indirect way. Most reviewers thus approved it. This shows that the reviewers were just passing their time doing robo-reviewing,or even not just paying much attention to the question. And clicking Looks OK whenever the see a question with something that looks like code.

Finally I mean to say that do not just think that if a question has code, it has to be ok. Please read the post and then review it.

To apply a analogy, I'll tell two well known quotes:

> Think before you leap.
>
> Do not judge a book by its cover.

Both of them apply here. The first one clearly means that always think carefully before you press a review button, either to approve or reject. The second quote applies here as most reviewers just have a glance at the question, and if it is properly formatted, long and has code, they just approve it. Which many times turns out to be wrong.

---

## Major Edit 1

> I agree the questions are "give me teh codez" and poor questions; my purpose with the comment about a 1 line answer is that this seems to rule out a "too broad" flag - a question which can be answered so concisely can't really be too broad. Which then leads back to my original question - what on earth is the best response.

Now this is a very good comment by Stuart Whitehouse. He clearly says that "give me teh codez" questions which can be answered in one-line, cannot be closed as too broad. I agree with this point.

So now here is what to do.

When you flag to close a question, you see a menu. In that, choose the off-topic option:

[image]

Next, you will see another menu:

[image]

I think the image shows what to choose, but for clarity, I'll put the text here:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Now let's see how can we close a "give me teh codez" question, which can be answered in one line, with this reason.

> Questions asking us to recommend or **find** a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow...(emphasis mine)

Now this clearly applies to "give me teh codez" questions. If you see the highlighted word "find", that is what they are exactly asking us to do. They are asking us to give code, which can in another way also mean for us to "find code for the OP". So now, the code giving reason is clearly put in this reason.

> Instead, **[describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question)** and what has been done so far to solve it (emphasis mine).

This line also clearly applies to "give me teh codez" questions. Questions are known as "give me teh codez" questions when they show no research, are poor quality, and are just asking us for code. This line says that you should tell what has been done till now. Otherwise, it is just another poor research question. And "give me teh codez" questions are always poor research questions. Thus, this line is also appropriate.

> they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam...

This line clearly applies to asking code questions. This is because, many users just post answers to gain reputation. There are going to be opinionated answers as there might be hundreds of ways to solve a problem.

Now I'll give an example where this reason has been used to close a "give me teh codez" question.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489737/how-do-i-morph-a-circle-into-a-rectangle-with-corner-radius-with-swift) question is closed with the exact same reason. It is just another "give me teh codez" question. I know that this question is not one-liner, but this is the only closed "give me teh codez" question I could find with very few lines. I think this example is sufficient.

**REQUEST:** Please do not delete the linked question in Major Edit 1. Downvote it if you feel so. This is because, in many meta posts I've come across, the linked question is deleted, and it makes a gap in that post. I don't think any bad will come if we just let one question not get deleted.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Ashish.  I agree with a lot of your logic;  my concern is that it appears to contradict the policy in the [first link in my question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x).

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse: Oh okay, I'll go and check that. Give me some time.

Comment: To illustrate how confusing this is, I don't think I would agree with either of your flags in the last ("For example") part of your question.  The first question which reduces to "how do I round to a multiple of 15", is certainly clear, it even includes multiple examples and required result.  It's also possible to answer in almost any language in one line of code: `Round(original_value / 15) * 15`.  To my mind, a question that can be answered in one line isn't "Too Broad", and so the question is valid, even if a bit meh

Comment: Likewise your [last example](http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11923124) regarding the volume, could plausibly have 1 line answers on some platforms such as "subscribe to event XYZ", or "listen for message WM_XYZ" or detect key XYZ.  I know little swift/iOS, but a concise answer seems plausible here.  I do agree it looks like a poor/low effort question, but doesn't seem too broad.  On the other hand whole seconds on Google found me the [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772832/program-access-to-iphone-volume-buttons), so I would have dup-flagged (which I've now done)

Comment: @Stuart: Well but both of the questions are still "give me the codez" question. The reviews you come across in the triage queue are meant for analyzing the quality of the post, not for finding dupes nor seeing if the answer is one-liner or ten-liner.  The main goal of the triage queue is to find out whether the post is good or bad. So when you take action on a "give me teh codez" question, you don't see whether it is a one-liner or ten-liner "give me the codez" question. A "give me the codez" question is a "give me the codez" question. I'm looking into the contradiction from your linked post.

Comment: I agree the questions are "give me teh codez" and poor questions;  my purpose with the comment about a 1 line answer is that this seems to rule out a "too broad" flag - a question which can be answered so concisely can't really be too broad.  Which then leads back to my original question - what on earth is the best reponse.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse: I just got a solution for your above comment. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse: Edited. Sorry if I took time, but actually I'm quite busy for a few days. I'm even looking into your contradiction issue, from your linked question. I have added the flag you should do for one-liner "give me teh codez" questions.

Comment: Why 3 downvotes? Can someone explain? Please tell why you don't agree with my answer? That will help me improve it and find a solution.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I downvoted your answer, because I don't agree with it (anymore). While *gimme teh codez* questions are an annoyance, they sometimes lead to general Q&As which have high value for future readers. I tend to despise the *fix my code for me* questions which you seem to like, because that's what you're recommending. Such questions lead to highly specific answers that may only be limited to the issue at hand and less so for a more general approach. If you don't like the question, open it in a new tab and downvote it, so that it gets deleted if no one bothers to respond. **Then skip.**

Comment: Come on. You basically said "*If the user narrows the type of code he wants, it would be awkward to close it as broad, so we close it as unclear.*" Doesn't seem like a good solution.

Comment: It really feels here like you're trying to shoehorn some of these questions into a close vote category when they don't really fit. Please see the answers to [What's the appropriate new/current close reason for “How do I do X?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253069/1157054). Often these low-effort questions may merit downvotes, but don't really fit into any close vote reason.

Comment: (cont.) If your concern is "but then low-quality questions might get answered", and you think that's a real problem, then open a [meta-tag:feature-request] to deal with that problem directly rather than trying to contort existing features into serving a purpose they weren't meant for. (Maybe you could suggest a new close-vote reason that better fits these questions, or perhaps recommend adding a feature which automatically closes low-score questions.)

Comment: By this logic, any and every question is a request to go "find" some information that the OP does not have.

Answer (score 5):

I would just use "Skip" or "Looks OK" and **downvote** if I were you. Those kinds of question are not off-topic provided they're a) not duplicates and b) sufficiently specific. And if they're well written by a person who's just too lazy to code or do some googling (but otherwise competent to post a question) you just can't close the question anyway.

The description of downvote is **"Shows poor research effort"**. That's the problem with such question.

Comment: This does appear to be the answer.  One minor problem is that you can't downvote from within the triage page.  It is, of course, possible to open the question up in a new tab; but this is (a) a nuisance, (b) made me as a novice reviewer feel I must be doing something wrong, and (c) given there are, as gnat noted, 150 000+ reviewers, probably not going to happen in the majority of cases.

Comment: @StuartWhitehouse Yeah I noticed that. I believe those questions do not really belong in the Triage in the first place, as no moderation action can make them any better.

Comment: Although triage doesn't handle these questions well, conceptually any question _belongs_ in the triage queue: it is by definition the first port of call for any question that might be iffy.  And so has to handle everything from outright spam to very good questions.  Triage is the process of deciding where the question really belongs.

Comment: "Downvote" is not an available option in Triage.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You could load the question in another tab and downvote there.