# Why am I getting Questions as audits in the Low Quality Posts queue?

Tags: support, feature-request, bug, review-audits

In the course of an unrelated discussion on [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320672/3486353), it was brought to my attention that on StackOverflow, there aren't supposed to be questions in the Low Quality Posts queue. However, with only a brief minute of flipping through the queue, I found an example where I was presented with a question for review:

[image: VLQ queue featuring a question!]

As is pretty clear from the quality of the question, this was an audit, and the rest of my non-audit review items seemed to be 100% answers rather than questions. If, as was asserted to me in the initial discussion, questions aren't shown on the Low Quality Posts queue normally, then why am I getting them as audits? Unless there's some reason for keeping them around, I'd suggest that any Questions are purged from the audit pool for this queue.

Answer (score 2):

> questions aren't shown on the Low Quality Posts queue normally, then why am I getting them as audits?

Questions are *no longer* shown in the LQP queue.  They once where.  The auditing is just out of date.

Comment: That makes sense. Shouldn't questions be purged from the audit pool, though, if they'll never be validly shown otherwise?

Comment: @sphanley Sure.