# Triage Queue: Needs Editing option -- Suggestion for improvement

Tags: feature-request, triage

I'm fairly new to Stack Overflow, and recently started working on the triage queue. I've seen lots of discussion in Meta regarding the triage queue, flags aging out or being disputed for very low quality or completely off-topic questions, and recognize that people like me are part of the problem -- I initially didn't understand the "requires editing" option.

I think a simple rewording of the help text that you provide while working the queue can improve things immensely. The following restatement of "requires editing", from one of the answers here, made things much clearer (the key being **without OP's help**):

> [Requires Editing - Needs grammar, code formatting, paragraph formatting, etc that can be applied **without OP's help**. If you can make sense of it in a quick pass but it is poorly worded or constructed, put it here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320536/what-is-the-best-triage-response-for-give-me-teh-codez-questions/320677#320677)

Also, I suggest that things that age out (or are never edited while being in the edit queue) automatically change to close, or at least are tagged on the web site with some information that would inform the visitor to the site that there may be issues with the question or answer.

There's a tremendous amount of crud that ends up being saved forever on Stack Overflow -- it's kind of like the bottom of my sock drawer. For the goal of being a "reference site", I think you need to err on the side of deletion rather than retention, to help the searcher find quality answers.

Comment: "_err on the side of deletion rather than retention_" unfortunately SO errs on the other side.  They would rather have a bit of clutter instead of deleting possibly useful content.

Comment: related: [We should clean up posts that should be improved but haven't been and won't be](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293457/we-should-clean-up-posts-that-should-be-improved-but-havent-been-and-wont-be)

Comment: @gnat I like that proposal. Ran the query--didn't see much use to retain those questions. And the criteria used are even more conservative than the ones I suggested. There'd still be a lot of trash left, but it would be an improvement.

Comment: There should be an indication of where "requires editing" goes: if the text was "send to the improvement queue", there might be less confusion.