# Excel questions with accepted answers should not have been deleted

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, close-reasons

My query is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44023789/excel-how-to-create-from-flat-file-to-cross-tabs) deleted question ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWklS.jpg)).

**a)**

As per *[Why and how are some questions deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)*,

> Questions that are extremely off topic, or of very low quality, may be removed at the discretion of the community and moderators.

Moderators can delete any question however I am looking for a reason why that question was deleted. Its obvious that it came to my notice because I have an accepted and up-voted answer and deletion of the question led to deletion of my answer(loss of reps is not a concern) as well.

As far as I can understand, the question was deleted because it was already closed and down voted. The question is not of good quality and does not not show any efforts taken by OP to solve the issue but its still clear what the requirement of the OP is.

Also, the question was asked and answered on *17-May-2017* and was deleted yesterday i.e. *22-Oct-2017*. So is there a time span for answer to be deleted or can question be deleted after any number of days from the date of asked or answered. (Although, as of now I guess, knowing this is not necessary for me)

Well, there's [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46537796/condition-to-pass-only-unique-values) question that was deleted after my answer was accepted. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvETX.jpg))

**b)**

I also agree with [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291342/6075259) answer, stating

> Give me the code is not a close reason according to SO rules but a downvote one.

Questions like ***"How to do something"*** or ***"Give me the code"*** could be down voted but should not be flagged as ***too broad*** and should be left to the other people whether they are interested in answering the question or not.

I am active on Excel related tags like [excel], [excel-formula], [excel-VBA], [VBA]. I've also observed that the questions with no efforts from OP tagged as [VBA] (this requires coding) are more likely to get flagged as ***"too broad"*** as compared to questions with no efforts tagged as [excel-formula] (this requires one liner formula). That means questions asking for formula are answered while questions asking for code are flagged. (I don't want to mention questions here but this has been the trend). So is it because people are ready to spend sometime answering one liner formulas but not the complete code and hence questions are flagged. Question I am referring here clearly shows what OP has and the desired output.

**Feature Request**

Finally, I would like to suggest that any question that has an accepted answer should not be deleted for one simple reason that the the problem of OP is solved and can be helpful to others.

Comment: Excel... and I bet nothing to do with vba. Obviously off topic. Site for unique programming stuff questions, anyone?

Comment: When you answer extremely low-quality and/or off-topic questions, having them deleted is a risk that you take.

Comment: @CodyGray - Completely agree with you, but this should be consistent through out the site. Why is this mostly applicable to questions where answers are not short or one liner.

Comment: It isn't "mostly applicable to questions where answers are not short or one liner". I don't know what you mean by that. One issue with consistency is that we simply get too many questions, and many low-quality/off-topic questions miss getting deleted. That's why I said "risk", rather than "guarantee".

Comment: somewhat related: [Can a question with an accepted answer be closed as unanswerable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258433/839601)

Comment: @CodyGray - Alright, agree with you. Would you like to comment something on "time span for answer to be deleted", just curious to know.

Comment: @Mrig the span is less a time one and more an attention one..... Basically when these questions gather enough attention, they get the proper treatment. Sometimes it happens in 15 minutes. Sometimes, way longer. There's really no easy way to tell how long it would take....

Comment: @Patrice - Thank you for the details.

Comment: I'm having a very difficult time understanding the questions you're trying to ask. What do you mean by "time span"? There is no time span. Things get deleted when they get deleted. That question was brought to my attention as part of a clean-up of the [convert] tag. I deleted more than 50 old, off-topic, and/or low-quality questions yesterday. This was one of them. I saw your answer, and I *sometimes* let a good answer save a bad question, but I didn't in this case, because that question was completely beyond the point of saving. No one would ever be able to find it to benefit from an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray - No issues, thank you for all the information.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> *"for one simple reason that the the problem of OP is solved and can be helpful to others."*

Just because it helped the OP is *no* indication that it's helpful for others.

Typo questions won't help future visitors.
Requirements dumps won't help future visitors.
*"Fix my website for me"* won't help future visitors.

Both questions you linked shouldn't have been answered in the first place.
Both are no more than a mediocre list of requirements, expecting SO's users to do all the work. Neither OP has shown any effort, or a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

So no. I disagree with blocking delete-votes on questions with accepted answers.

Comment: "Fix my website for me" certainly will not help anyone except for the OP. But if you'll see the question I'm talking about is quite a generic problem and can be helpful to others.

Comment: They're problem statements lacking any sign of effort from the OP.

Comment: @Mrig In the event that anyone else actually had the same problem, how would they find that question?  It doesn't even describe the problem, it just lists some input data and expected output data, nothing else.  Unless someone else not only has the same problem, but *the exact same sample data* (and probably not even then) they aren't going to even find that question.

Comment: @Servy - But the same kind of questions are being answered if it's a one liner code and are not flagged. Cerbus

Comment: @Mrig: Just because other people do it, doesn't mean it's okay. Problem dumps like that ___must___ be closed. Regardless of how long the answer is.

Comment: @Mrig Then work to address that problem by not answering those other bad questions, voting to close them as appropriate, etc.  There simply aren't enough people moderating the site appropriately to effectively moderate all of the bad content that gets posted.  The fact that there is other bad content not properly moderated doesn't mean posting bad content is okay.

Comment: @Servy - Sounds satisfactory. But what about "Give me the code is not a close reason according to SO rules but a downvote one". Cerbrus

Comment: @Mrig That's not a close reason in and of itself, however such questions have a very high probability of meeting some existing closure criteria.

Comment: Criteria like "too broad", for example.

Comment: Thank you both for the explanation. @Servy Cerbrus