# Why was my question put on hold as too broad?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

Yesterday, I asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570265/how-to-develop-a-simple-pool-table-in-c, I have edited several times but it still seems too broad. I was suggested to delete it, but I don't agree. I want to understand what's wrong in my question, so in this way I can improve myself and don't make the same error anymore.

All suggestions are welcome

Comment: I'm so tempted to close vote this against: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259940/with-the-new-why-isnt-this-code-working-we-dont-have-a-specific-enough-close

Comment: @rene Sorry I don't get What you mean...

Comment: @xxx They mean _"gimme teh codes plz"_ is off-topic, although there's not really a direct close reason for such questions.

Comment: I can close vote your question as a duplicate but if I do no-one can answer your question, it will be instantly closed.

Comment: see also [How to handle a question that asks many things](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267059/839601)

Comment: @xxx Also note [on hold] isn't the same as _deletion_.

Answer (score 10):

Your question is too broad because you fail to explain what we don't have to explain. You ask us where you can learn certain concepts: That is asking for an off-site resource, which is off-topic.

You have tagged your question with c++, mfc, sdi and visual-studio. You talk about a pool-table and collisions of balls.

Do we need to start with explaining how MFC fits in designing algorithms for the several algorithms you need? Or is it enough to explain how a simple formula can be consumed so that you can go from there? I assume you tagged SDI because you want a single document interface? What is holding you back creating one?

Based on what you provided I have the impression we need to work out the algorithms for you as well.

It is easy to make it less too broad. You provide the MFC class you have for ball or collision and then ask about a small detail regarding that implementation. That is a question some of us might be able to answer without writing a tutorial.

Comment: _"It is easy to make it less too broad. "_ Depends. In that actual case OP didn't even started to try anything.

Comment: OK , Are you telling me that I can post question about specific code but I can not have some "suggested" on How to learn something? Is this?

Comment: @xxx Exactly, we don't give any unspecific _suggestions_ unless you show something you already tried out so far.

Answer (score 6):

> I want to understand what's wrong in my question, so in this way I can improve myself and don't make the same error anymore.

Improving *too broad* questions is pretty hard if you didn't try anything concrete yet, because you'll need to provide very specific programming related problems you have with code that you already have been written.

Just to ask for ready made code, pointers, examples, tutorials or such is still off-topic and doesn't meet the Stack Overflow question quality policies.

---

> Someone knows where can I learn these concepts?

This still asks for 3rd party resources, which is blatantly off-topic.

Comment: this could also refer to some other "similar" topics in Stack Overflow that I didn't find before asked the question....I don't ask 3rd party resources.

Comment: @xxx What do you mean _"similar topics"_? Did you find such answered in a proper way? If so, note that policies had changed over time.