# Why is this question too broad?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373042/hiding-ms-access-interface-when-scripting-with-msaccess-exe) the other day, and it was soon put on hold by a moderator as too broad. I'm aware of this close reason and tried to see how it applied to my question, but I still wasn't sure why my question was too broad. I attempted to get some feedback by commenting under my question, but there wasn't any reply or further action it seemed.

If you look at the edit history, you'll see that I removed a "postscript" paragraph that basically stated "other suggestions welcome", since I thought to myself "hey, maybe I could accomplish this task using a different approach that someone might be able to offer". I suspected that maybe this paragraph was making the answer set not narrow enough, so I went ahead and edited it out. Unfortunately, the hold is still there (though I did get three reopen votes, to which I promptly added my own when I realized it).

So I have two questions, closely related:

1. Why was the original question put on hold as too broad?
2. Is the current form of the question really still too broad?

I've read [this useful QA](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it) but am still not sure where my question is going wrong.

Comment: Since you seem insistent on getting an answer by posting on Meta, I've removed the meta comments from your question, and redirected the discussion here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks for that clean-up and redirect. For the record, I'm not "insistent on getting an answer" to my original question; by all my efforts at answering it myself so far, I'm inclined to believe there is no answer. I am, however, insistent on getting an answer to why the question was too broad. I'm not being rhetorical; I believe the mod had a good reason to do what he did, and I simply want to know what that reason was so that I can subtract one more iota from my still considerable SO-newbie-ness. If he doesn't have time to clarify (which I totally understand), maybe Meta does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe it is too broad. It's a very good question, actually. I've cast the final reopen vote, and your question has been reopened.

For further validation, the first (unedited) version of your post was also reasonable.

Comment: Thanks for this and your participation at the original question, Lynn. At this point I'm assuming I won't be getting any offered explanations of the original reason for the question being too broad, so the accept here goes to you. (Also, +1 given earlier)

Comment: It is really frustrating how people flag questions inappropriately.