# Given that questions may be closed for subjective reasons, what can an asker do to get a legitimate question open?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, reopen-closed

I was wondering the same things as this question:  [Breaking down "too broad" and trying to understand it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258589/1766230) 
...to which [the answer is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259857/1766230):

> All close reasons are subjective

If an otherwise well designed question is closed down due to subjective reasons (which could be based entirely off incorrect assumptions or misunderstandings on part of the closers), what can an asker do?

I've had a few questions closed, most recently this one: [Is HTML Turing Complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30719221/1766230) as Too Broad... Even if I edit the question multiple times, it is very difficult to get helpful feedback on how to improve the question, and almost impossible to get it re-opened. Even if it were re-opened, it would be filled with a long thread discussing the edits, which is no longer useful to most readers.

- Is it best to start a new question asking the same thing?
- Is there any kind of "appeal" forum?
- Should the asker always try to pre-emptively defend against all potential subjective misunderstandings?

Comment: Note that another, similar question that's **five years old** does not make yours on-topic; times change. It's also worth revisiting your assumption that it's *"a legitimate question"* in light of the five other users who've suggested otherwise!

Comment: Anyway, your specific question is not on-topic: [help/on-topic]. Or how is HTML's missing turing-completeness "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"?

Comment: The question is certainly answerable. I suppose whether or not it is "practical" is subjective. ... but "off-topic" is probably a much more satisfying close tag than the incorrect use of "too broad".

Comment: It's a really crappy question. People close really crappy questions (which is good), sometimes for reasons that are not intuitive when the close reason text is literally applied to the post. Your question is not too broad when you consider that the answer is simply "no"; but how one arrives at this "no" can take thousands of words to explain. That you have to ask that question at all shows that your understanding of the concepts involved is severely lacking - namely, turing completeness is a concept that only applies to programming languages, and html is not a programming language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First: **edit your question to address the closer's concerns**.

If you don't do that, your chances of being re-opened are next to nothing. Once you have done that, you are *automatically* in the re-open queue. You could also consider asking users in your tag's chat to review the question.

To your specific ideas:

> Is it best to start a new question asking the same thing?

**NO**. Do not *ever* do this. This is a good way to get a question-ban and annoy the very users you want to help you.

> Is there any kind of "appeal" forum?

Meta, and chat, are the closest things we have. Of course editing does put the post in the re-open review queue as well.

> Should the asker always try to pre-emptively defend against all potential subjective misunderstandings?

Yes... and no. Make sure your question is clear, and properly scoped, and not a duplicate. Do *not* just go through the close reasons and say "My question does not match this close reason because X. My question does not match this other close reason because Y".

Finally, if you have a long and obsolete comment thread, just flag the post with a custom flag asking for cleanup.