# Over-broad or not?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

Am I being over-zealous or isn't [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32337272/522444) too broad for this site? What test should I use to determine the boundary for this type of problem?  Isn't a statement such as,

> "If so, could you share your thoughts and advices (challenges and difficulties, if that's the case)?"

by definition over-broad?

Possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it) I know, but I'm curious about this specific circumstance.

Comment: Crazy-broad. Burn it to *ashes* (or just VTC)

Comment: It's posed for deletion right now. On your service [tag:Java] guys ;-) ...

Comment: And done .... :-)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: next how about this [beg for code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32336923/522444) question?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Also done, but was different. Your original needed one more downvote, while that one needed a close vote actually ;-)! I'm friendly with you Java guys, but don't pull my finger for every question you think that's prone for deletion. I'd go to fart intermittently since I'm not really experienced with the programming language.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels We've often enough been a good team for closing/deleting questions carrying both [tag:Java] and [tag:C++] tags :-) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> > *"If so, could you share your thoughts and advices (challenges and difficulties, if that's the case)?"*

It's border line between ***too broad*** and ***opinion based*** actually.

Close worthy anyway, just choose one of the mentioned close reasons above, doesn't matter much which one.

If you also want to delete that question as quickly as possible add a downvote, and wait for more downvotes agreeing with yours.

As from your comments about the [*begging for code question*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32336923/522444) I'm frequently close voting such questions as ***too broad*** within my favourite language tag ([c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)), and mostly ignore additional unrelated spamming tags.

Comment: a very minor reminder: one of the close reasons should be"primarily opinion-based" but not "opinion-pased"

Comment: Such as [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416154/employer-wont-allow-php-options-and-why).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels At your service, but please don't ping me every times ;-) ...