# How to improve an on-hold question?

Tags: feature-request, on-hold

I posted this question: 
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38953500/design-architecture-for-two-sided-marketplace-in-one-mobile-app)

The question was downvoted and then put on hold without any explanation.
I would like to Edit/Improve the question if more specific feedback could be provided.

The question is mainly intended for people who has already encountered such a problem and could share their experience.

Yes, the answer to the question is not black and white, and it probably could be implemented in different ways with different approaches, but that exactly what I want to hear.

Is it possible to force users to post a reason for downvote/on hold so the person who receive it can improve his questions in the future?

The reason:

*Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*

Thank you, I see it... 
**My question is mainly: How do I improve it? (How do I make it on-topic?)**

**Edit**
I would like to clear some issues that were raised

- I **do agree** my question is in the gray area between the *"common SO question"* and the *"discuss/opinion Question"*. (I miss that discuss/opinion are not allowed [How to Ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ,I didn't find its not allowed ).And as most of you say it on second area I will not argue with you.
- I **don't agree** that the Q is too broad is exactly how I mean and how it suppose to be *Design/Architecture for two-sided marketplace in one Mobile App*.What is two-sided marketplace is explained in the question "close to what we see in the Airbnb app". Splitting the question to sub questions  doesn't make sense coz it miss the global question.
- I **don't agree** that  IOS creeped in Android or vice versa , In ideal it can be nice that two platforms would have the same architecture (don't you think it nice to think about two platforms as one solving the problems for one will solve for another)
- I **don't agree** that this Q need a code sample, the question is not about the code.(I wouldn't expect a code answer).
- I **do agree** I asked for opinion/expertise from people who have the right expertise with certain limitation/restriction which must met. (Probably its SO not exactly the place to ask for it)

Comment: "put on hold as primarily opinion-based". Says so under the question.

Comment: There's a reason in the yellow box: _"Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise."_ You might be able to narrow down the question by editing it so that it's actually answerable with facts.

Comment: I mean that I need more specific feedback to improve the question

Comment: @Mike.r there is little you can do for a purely opinion based. The problem is that you are under the impression "a question for people with the same problem to share their experience" is on topic. You'll have to change that Q a lot for it to be on topic :/

Comment: @Mike.R Question closure **never  appears without explanation**, so I don't get what you're asking about?

Comment: Wow. I took a look at the question since i did feel some pity for you but... as the question is, it looks unsalvagable. So for the next one, 1) keep the questions small and on topic; a whole project isnt fit for one question. 2) somehow iOS creeped into the question about android? 3) you're asking about singletons when you're really after "how do i design a two-sided marketplace". What *is* a two-sided marketplace? 4) you're asking people to be flexible because things will change during development. that's great, however you've shown no development of your own. 5) asking for opinions/expertise

Comment: I think your question is too broad. Split it in multiple more well definied, narrower, more focused questions and they will be on topic and probably also upvoted (if they are well formulated).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Breaking down “too broad” and trying to understand it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question was (as already mentioned in Pekka's answer) put on hold for being primarily opinion based. There isn't really much you can fix here without entirely changing it.

In general, SO is not a good fit for this type of question, and you should look for another place to ask this. Not every question can be edited into a reopenable state, and yours most likely can't without, again, changing its entire meaning and direction.

Answer (score 10):

There *is* an explanation below the close message:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.
>   If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

That also addresses your key point: this kind of question, sadly, isn't on topic on Stack Overflow because as a class, those questions tend to generate extended discussion, opinion, and spam, all of which don't really fit the site.

Comment: I see the reason ... but the reason is too broad. I am not sure  how to improve the question.

Comment: I'm afraid the question is so clearly in opinion-based territory that it's really hard to give any specific advice on how to improve it other than "look for a place to ask elsewhere".

Comment: Pekka but that exactly what I need an another opinion of somebody who encounter that problem and discuss his approach.

Comment: @Mike.R What _you need_ and _what the site is for_ don't always align. There are questions you have (like this one) that aren't a good fit for SO.

Comment: @Magisch can you suggest how to improve it?

Comment: @Mike.R See my answer. Unless you want to completly change what its about, I suggest to let it be and find a site better fit for such questions and ask it there.

Comment: Tnx @Magisch, That the biggest community I know for asking this type of  questions . If I change the direction / meaning it won't be the question I want. Must admit don't even know what to do... spent few hours do get down voted for no specific reason:)

Comment: No specific reason? Being off topic on a site means the downvotes are expected. Don't play the martyr card plz....

Comment: @Mike.R You weren't downvoted for "no specific reason".  You were downvoted for a very specific reason.  You simply don't like that reason.  The fact that you really want to ask the question as is, even though the question is not appropriate here, doesn't change the fact that it's not appropriate here.