# Should we close this question as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-close

Whilst reviewing answers in the *Late Answers* queue I came across an answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016128/where-is-java-scripting-engine-used/):

> Could someone of you show me how to effectively use "Scripting Engine" inside Java?
>
> What are all the right use-case to use scripting engine?
>
> Is there any open source project using "Scripting Engine"?
>
> One thing comes to mind is "Closure, Functional programming" support is possible, but it is more of technical use than "Application Requirement"
>
> Edit Added: Configurable, Plugins are ok. But still so many patterns (visitor, decorator) on high level can do the same.
>
> I don't know the requirement well... how effectively it could be used in J2EE patterns... where it could complement with the existing patterns.
>
> Moreover I would like to see more answers with some business usecases may be like finding complex discount for a product during sale based on membership or location. finding ranking for a complex algorithm. Especially why not java in some scenario? (or C# in .Net world)

The question is now quite old and back then it may have been on topic however according to the guidelines now I feel this if off-topic falling under:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

It may also be considered *too broad*.

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42579114/6375113):

> You should use Math.pow(2,3) instead of using cap symbol.
>
> So the final syntax will be like,
>
> ```
> engine.eval("print((5 * Math.pow(2,3) + 2 * 3 % 2) * 4)");
> ```

To me this doesn't do anything to answer the question so I did flag as *NAA* leaving a comment for the OP.

Should this question be closed as such so no other answers can be added? As in my opinion this question is *off-topic* and/or *too broad* which doesn't lend itself to attracting **good** answers.

<sup>I don't believe this question is a duplicate of this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it). My issue isn't understanding *too broad*. My issue is should we close this specific question? Commenting on the question and asking them to be more specific would seem senseless given the age of it and that it has existing answers.</sup>

Comment: I don't know any Java, but how the topic jumped from what is being asked to "You should use Math.pow(2,3) instead of using cap symbol."??????????????!!

Comment: as for the answer you refer it should be flagged as NAA, I commented on that there. Two more answers in there should be flagged NAA as well: [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36148662/839601) (which is a new question dumped into the answer field, likely by user trying to circumvent question block) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1016154/839601) (textbook [meta-tag:link-only-answer])

Comment: @gnat those answers have now been deleted. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I fail to see how the answer is not an answer. It is most definitely an answer, just not an answer to the question asked. Such answers should be downvoted and delete voted, not flagged as NaA.

Comment: @TinyGiant if it's not an answer to the question then it's not an answer and I'm unsure how else I can flag it other than NAA. I'm not arguing here either, I genuinely don't know how else to flag it.

Comment: See: [A minor change to the description of the “not an answer” flag: “the question” → “a question”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286229/a-minor-change-to-the-description-of-the-not-an-answer-flag-the-question). If it is not obvious from the answer alone that it is _not an answer_ (meaning a question, or something else that is precluded from being an answer), don't use the NaA flag. Downvote and delete vote if you can. If it is a comment on another post, but that is not obvious from the answer itself, you can use a custom moderator flag detailing which post it should be a comment on.

Comment: @TinyGiant appreciate the link and comments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Should the question be closed as such so no other answers can be added?

You shouldn't close a question so more answers can't be added. You should close questions because it isn't feasible to have all answers to the question, or the amount of approaches is non-trivial, or it isn't clear what is being asked, or what is being asked is known to cause problems. Closing a question so it doesn't get new answers isn't what SE meant to do.