# Why is my question too broad?

Tags: support, specific-question, needs-more-focus

I asked this question:

[Running two different sessions of RStudio on the same Windows pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144864/running-two-different-sessions-of-rstudio-on-the-same-windows-pc)

It has been put on hold because too broad. I don't understand why. It seems to me the question is quite simple: if I open two different sessions of R Studio under Windows, and they both run the same R scripts in two different directories, will they conflict or will everything work as smoothly as if I ran a single session? The scripts are long, but they basically read files which are in the script directories, write files in the same directories, launch an executable with the R instruction `system`, read the executable output and iterate until convergence (it's an NLS regression). I added all these details in the question, except maybe the NLS part. I also described my system, how much RAM I have and how much RAM I think one R session is using (according to the Task Manager). I'm not sure what else I can add to make the question more specific. Can you help me?

PS the executable code reads an input file and write an output file in the same folder where all the scripts (AND the .exe) are located. I think this was clear from the question, but I admit I didn't spell it out in clear words, so I just updated the question, in case this was the problem.

Comment: related: [Breaking down “too broad” and trying to understand it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258589/839601)

Comment: Perhaps the close voters are suggesting you just try it and see.

Comment: last part of the question... seems like opinion based.

Comment: @RobertLongson heh, that could indeed be an option :) I will try. However, I was looking for an authoritative answer from experts on this site, because if I just try and it works, I'll never know if it was dumb luck (and in my next project it won't work anymore), or if there are "theoretical" reasons why I should expect it  to work for most reasonable codes. I mean, maybe it is to be expected that under Windows 7 two different sessions of R Studio ran in two different directories are like two different codes (e.g, Excel and Word) and they won't conflict, because the OS will take care of that?

Comment: @RobertLongson I'm not a programmer and I don't have a formal training in Computer Science, so I might be overlooking something obvious here.

Comment: @SagarV why do you say so? It wasn't closed as "opinion based". Are you referring to this sentence: "Can you tell me if I can go with my plan, or if I need to change something?"? If so, then how can I improve it in your opinion? Would "Will the two sessions coexist happily, or do I risk that there could be runtime errors, such as one session overwriting files written from the other session, memory corruption, etc.?" be better, in your opinion?

Comment: @RobertLongson I tried and actually it works (or at least it hasn't still thrown any error...the full simulation takes in excess of 4 hours to run, so I won't be able to say for sure until later). Yay!! I hope this is the norm for the problem setting I described, and not just a lucky coincidence which wouldn't hold for a different project.

Comment: @DeltaIV the problem is _Can you tell me if I can go with my plan, or if I need to change something?_ , some people agree with your current plan and they will tell you it is right. some will tell you it is wrong. it will vary from person to person. That's why opinion based questions are not allowed in SO. anyway, I neither closed it nor casted any vote on it.

Comment: @SagarV no problem - even if you did, I wasn't criticizing anyone, I was just trying to understand how (if at all possible) I could improve the question so that it could be reopened. If there's no way to salvage it, I will delete it - questions can be closed or deleted every now and then, it's no big deal.

Comment: my personnel suggestion is, use **bold** and _italic_ to highlight important parts. the text content is too big and people find difficult to catch exactly what you want if you didn't highlight it.

Comment: I've seen people separate the background info from their actual question with headings. This generally isn't necessary but given that the current answer thinks a lot of your background info contains questions, you might find it useful to separate them out. I'd also drop the last sentence (which is kind of redundant) and emphasize that your questions are: 1) Can the files get corrupted? 2) Can the instances conflict with each other?

Comment: @BSMP you got the gist of my question perfectly. Today or tomorrow I will edit it to make the two questions stand out, and remove some distracting details.

Answer (score 6):

There are a small number of defined close reasons, plus the option to write a custom close reason. Many questions could fit more than one close reason as different people see or place emphasis on different aspects of the question. There are large numbers of poor questions asked on this site and expecting people to write custom reasons is asking too much of them. So people often choose the close reason they think best fits the problems they see in the question. The site is set up to allow the community to curate poor questions quickly without a big overhead.

Taking some phrases from your question:

- I'm performing a complex simulation
- I need to experiment
- I could do it one setting at a time ... But it would be faster
- Thus, I was thinking if I could just
- My only worries are
- I suspect it would work, but I don't know
- Can you tell me if I can go with my plan, or if I need to change something?

From these phrases, you are expressing your uncertainty on several issues and you appear to be asking several things. So I think the too broad is a reasonable assessment. On the other hand, the final "Can you ..." question suggests that you are asking for the pros and cons of the earlier options. For that it might be that a close reason of primarily opinion based would apply.

Comment: Sorry, I have to disagree. I'm not asking multiple questions: I'm asking just two questions, which are those which @BSMP summarized perfectly in her/his comment. The rest is additional background, but not additional questions. Maybe my way of expressing myself got in the way of delivering a clear question. I will try to fix this tomorrow.

Comment: @DeltaIV writing a good question is difficult. You have to think clearly about the problem and also about how it will be seen and interpreted by its readers. You took to trouble to ask for guidance here (which is a good thing). Because of that, BSMP and I and others looked at your question more carefully. We have different viewpoints and so you have a variety of feedback. Hopefully that will help you rewrite the question more clearly.