# Why does a general question get closed?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

I answered this question yesterday that looked legitimate, but it got closed for being too broad, and I don't understand why:
*[What does subscribe do, and how it is related to Observable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767880/what-does-subscribe-do-and-how-it-is-related-to-observable)*.

It's not a question like "*How to deal with reactive functional programming in Angular?*" which would be far too broad. The question is clear and asks only for a an explanation about a single concept:

> What is an `Observable` and why do we always have to call `observable.subscribe()`?

I agree there is no code or context, but I don't think a general question like that needs such things.

[From the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in
>   them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development …
>
> then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

So my question is:

Should general questions about programming concepts (*"What is ... ?"*) be avoided on Stack Overflow, in favor of more technical ones ("*How to ...*")? If no, what does this question lacks to be kept opened?

Comment: Instead of asking what is this, what does this mean. Give people for example a scenario where you had to use that or a bit of code where you used it, but you werent to sure why or what you used it for. It is like asking what is blue, instead of saying i have a ball made of rubber why is it blue and not black ( black gets hot faster and it can pop) for example.

Comment: I am sorry but that's just not the same question. Why wouldn't that be interesting to have a definition of what is blue ?

Comment: Let me try to explain it to you like this.. [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbOuCBuQepI) This is the first thing on google comming up when searching for * What is an Observable *. You could also have googled this. But instead you go on stack overflow asking the question millions of others ask. IF you wanted a different answer then on google you maybe should have specified or/and gave us your problem with your question.

Comment: First, that's not *my* question and I really don't like the fact you imply that I am too lazy to google something while **I am not the guy who asks** but the guy who answers ! Secondly, one of the aims of stack overflow is to keep a high-quality Q/A database regarding programming. Is there a question about what is an `Observable` tagged as js, rxjs or angular ? NOPE, only one is about .net .

Comment: OMG Sorry..... I thought this was regarding you making that post ( your answer is very neat ) the question on the other hand is well read my recent comments back, the question is indeed broad like i explained as above. This was nowhere near targetted at you @n00dl3 I misread the post and I thought it was your post.

Comment: it could be argued to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37364973/angular-promise-vs-observable

Comment: @Tanner Maybe you're right, it's not a problem to me if it is closed as a duplicate, I just did not agree with the "too broad" close reason. On the other hand I am not sure it is the same question because the one you pointed is a comparison with promises. Anyway that's another debate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breaking down "too broad" and trying to understand it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch we don't have a "no research" reason to close (that's a specified reason for downvotes), but people often use too broad or unclear as equivalents if they want to vote to close.

Comment: It's sad to see so many people downvoting the great answer posted just because the question is a beginner level one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree with the closure of that question.

Although they get a lot of hate, there is nothing wrong with a beginner-level question, as long as they fit within our format.

I'm sure that the close-voters would point you to [this explanation of the "too broad" close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it) as an explanation of why they voted to close. I don't think this question is too broad, however, and I think your answer serves as testament that it can be adequately answered in our format. Explaining a single concept as it's used in a particular library in a specific context seems like a sufficiently scoped topic to be welcome here.

There is nothing wrong with "What is...?" questions on Stack Overflow, as long as they are reasonably scoped and related to programming. As I've said countless times, resist the urge to turn this site into a "debug my code" help desk. We can, and should, do more than that drudgery.

As such, I've re-opened the question.

Anyone who thinks that the question is not useful is welcome to downvote it. Several people already have done so. That would be the appropriate way to express a feeling that the question is too basic, shows inadequate research effort, etc.

Note that it is possible the question may be a duplicate. I'm not a subject expert here, so I cannot evaluate the suitability of the proposed duplicate, nor can I go hunt for others myself. There would be nothing wrong with closing the question as a duplicate, if someone can find a suitable target. A moderator could even migrate your answer over to the "master" question.

Comment: Thank you @CodyGray, after a bit of searching, I don't think there is an actual duplicate, the indicated one is about java, and there is actually the same question about the .net implementation.