# How can I improve my "too broad" question so it doesn't look "too broad"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54567794/how-can-i-make-a-multiplayer-game-where-a-host-hosts-a-game-and-others-can-choos) (Please see [the first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54567794/1) because I have edited it) today and it got closed as too broad.

Before asking the question, I knew that this might be thought of as a "broad" question, which is why I added the last part:

> So, specifically, I want to know:
>
> - Which VC(s) should have a browser?
> - Which VC(s) should have an advertiser?
> - Which VC should hold the single MCSession object?
> - If one of my ideas was the right thing to do, how can the problem I described be solved?

I think the above already shows that this is not one of those "give me the code questions".

From this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it) and the description of the close reason, I know that "too broad" means a post satisfies one or more of these:

- have too many possible answers
- answers would be too long
- contains multiple distinct questions

I think my question would not have too many possible answers because I am just deciding which VC is the browser and which is the advertiser. Multipeer Connectivity is not a framework that allows you to do things in many different ways.

I don't think answers would be too long because they would be answering "Which VC(s) should have a browser?" plus a short explanation of why that is, and " Which VC(s) should have an advertiser?" plus a short explanation of why that is, and so on. One should be able to do this in "a few paragraphs" as the help center says.

I also do not think that the questions I listed in the last part are "distinct". You can't really answer one without also answering the others. An advertiser would be useless without a browser, and vice versa. I don't know how to further make my problem smaller.

It might be that I chose a bad title, making people think it's one of those "How do a build a forum in PHP" questions. I am just talking about and trying to solve my problem on a higher level of abstraction than the code level.

So what is a better title and/or how can the body be improved?

Or is this question more suitable on GameDev SE?

Comment: I think you should drop all the talk about view controllers. Your problem boils down to the last bullet point, the relationship between "advertiser" and "browser" across devices. Try to refocus on that.

Comment: I personally also don't really think it's too broad as-is, but voters sometimes find design-y questions to be so, since there is, strictly speaking, almost always a few different paths to take.

Comment: Well, the last bullet is "contains multiple distinct questions", and your question contains multiple questions. If you actually can't answer one without also answering the others, why ask the others?

Comment: @JoshCaswell do you think I would get more helpful answers on game dev SE then?

Comment: Having 4 bullet points suggests it ought to be 4 questions.

Comment: @Raedwald But not having them makes it sound like I am asking for code, which I am not, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't know GameDev at all...SoftwareEngineering.SE should be a good fit, though.

Comment: _"Well, the last bullet is 'contains multiple distinct questions', and your question contains multiple questions"_ I find this to be an unnecessarily literal viewpoint, similar to saying a post "isn't a question" because there's no '?' in its body. The key word there is **distinct**.

Comment: @JoshCaswell You could maybe make a case that the first two questions aren't distinct questions, and it's just two ways of phrasing the same question.  The next two are *absolutely* distinct questions.

Comment: Curious, but have you researched about this and failed to find how others had implemented your idea or any sample codes/projects? I'd be surprised if this is something that hasn't been done before...

Comment: @AndrewT. I thought so as well. But I don't know the term for this "hosts host rooms and players can choose a room to join" mechanic. And entering that phrase into Google didn't give me any useful results...

Comment: @Sweeper Well from what I read, this technology is basically to do something very similar to what Dark Souls does (peer to peer client and host discovery), except Dark Souls does everything automagically behind the scenes without any kind of manual intervention. Could be useful to research into the mechanics behind that game.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'm not sure I'm seeing much hope for this question.

Without being an expert in the domains of either iOS or game development, my main takeaways are:

- You want to make a game.
- You want to wire the game in specific ways.
- You want to know which way(s) to wire the game.

You have a question, but you don't really have something we can answer here because there are many ways to go about doing this kind of thing.  The premise of your question, as highlighted by the four bullet points you list, don't have any concrete or objectively answerable *thing* about them - the common answer would be to use whichever `ViewController` makes sense, but the "makes sense" part is what you're trying to figure out.

This is why it's too broad.

I'm not convinced this question would have a future anywhere else on the network, since it's...too abstract.  There's not enough "work" here to suggest that an answer can be provided by someone here without requiring us to cover lots and lots of ground just to come up with something serviceable.