# Mark as duplicate after 2.5 years

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

Yesterday I had reason to re-visit a question that I asked back on June 5 2015, "[Use images like checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30663562/use-images-like-checkboxes)" as I needed the same solution again.

I noticed that the question had been marked as a duplicate. However, it was marked as a duplicate on January 21st, 2018.

I'm a little confused honestly as to why somebody would see fit to mark a +154 rated question with 41k views, over 100 favourites and a popular answer with +280 upvotes as a duplicate - when the question they referred to ([Change checkbox check image to custom imag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270987/change-checkbox-check-image-to-custom-image)e) was not really the same thing and had a much weaker answer.

Now I realise that I am sort of just as bad, coming over to meta to rase this 14 months after the fact, though I only saw this a couple of weeks ago and have stewed on it long enough to actually come over here and seek opinion.

<strike>Opinion: *Should you only be allowed to do a solo "mark as duplicate" within a much shorter time frame (say, 6 weeks) to questions that haven't clearly been of huge benefit to the community?*</strike>

**Edit**: Thank you for the discussion. I have updated my opinion as it is indeed, not a productive idea.

Comment: @yivi In what way does it argue against my point please? The link you provided argues that an older question was marked as a duplicate referencing a newer question. If that had happened I wouldn't care (actually it seems like a sensible thing to do)

Comment: Passage of time has nothing to do with it in any case. The only relevant thing is where the more valuable answer lives.

Comment: @Gimby: Agree. Although you could argue that a +280 answer is probably the better answer.

Comment: Since this question is tagged feature-request, voting on the question might indicate agreement or disagreement with your proposal. Although I agree that the duplicate closure is suboptimal, I'm inclined to downvote since I don't think that limiting the gold-badge hammer to a shorter timeframe is a good idea.

Comment: @BDL What grinds my gears the most is that the accepted answer on the older question is a jquery answer where jquery was absolutely not part of the question...

Comment: While the point that it's all about the quality of question and answer is valid, I think that here the older one clearly has better and more thorough answers, even when not considering votes or views. I'd be in favor of reversing the dupe direction here.

Comment: Note that mixing in _Should you only be allowed to do a solo "mark as duplicate" within a much shorter time frame (say, 6 weeks) to questions that haven't clearly been of huge benefit to the community?_ is probably gaining you lots of downvotes. I strongly disagree with that. Duplicates are about consolidating knowledge and helping future visitors find what they need, and there's no timeframe on that.

Comment: What @ErikA said. I downvoted to express disagreement with the feature-request, but I agree the closure is the wrong way around.

Comment: @ErikA and Cerbrus, thank you for the comments, you are both entirely correct and I have updated my original question.

Comment: "I have updated my opinion" `git commit -m "chg: actually let's not do that"`

Answer (score 12):

I agree that the dupe target is the wrong way around. Especially since the accepted answer on the dupe target is, well, horrible.

I've voted to re-open the closed question, but since it's tagged [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), and not [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), I can't un-hammer it.

---

The question is now re-opened, so [Change checkbox check image to custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10270987/change-checkbox-check-image-to-custom-image) can now be close-voted.

Comment: why you would want to close that question? as duplicated?

Comment: Because one of the two _is_ a duplicate of the other. I just think the closure was the wrong way around.

Comment: if you see the most voted answer you'll see that that''s the best non-js approach for both questions, therfore the latter question should closed, not this one IMHO

Comment: The fiddle in that answer doesn't even seem to work.

Comment: are you referring to this ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13953070/3448527

Comment: No, other answer by Tony. That answer doesn't even have the _required_ HTML to make it work.

Comment: but I'm referring to that answer, which is the most voted of all, that can fit both questions

Comment: ... and is incomplete.

Comment: By today's standards, the resurrected question should be closed as too broad, because the OP made no attempt to solve the problem themselves and do not even demonstrate any research effort.

Comment: @tripleee: read the last paragraph in that question. It's not like he hasn't put any thought into it at all.

Comment: @tripleee According to this related meta (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it) examples of "Too broad" are things like "How do I write a web browser?" or "How do I code a forum in PHP". Whilst I didn't come with a _extremely specific question_ it remains my honest opinion that my question benefited the community in general and helped more people than it annoyed. I didn't even know I could achieve animations in CSS until I got the help from that answer. Surely that's the essence of StackOverflow. I stand to be corrected.

Comment: Exhibit B: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x -- there doesn't seem to be a firm consensus on this, and I am no web programmer, so perhaps my judgment is cloudy; but I would at least expect some sort of commentary on the actual code driving the CAPTCHA in the screen shot, for example.

Comment: the question was closed as duplicate and now reopened again ... strange move from the same user.