# Is asking for solutions to a problem that has more than one possible solution too broad for SO?

Tags: discussion

I just had my [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64383835/c-sharp-create-lambda-over-given-method-that-injects-first-paramater) closed due to being duped. The question is about problem that can be solved in different ways, AFAIK. I’ve shown my research by selecting a single way of solving a problem then running into trouble *I was well aware*. The dupe linked is about the problem in my concrete solution. But my question was not why this concrete solution fails, but *are there any other solutions*?

After discussion in comments, the closer told me that

> Asking "is there any possible way?" just isn't on topic here; it's way too broad

So I clarified:

> Why is asking for possible solutions of concrete problem too broad?

And received:

> If I come up with (for example) three different ways to accomplish the final goal, how am I to know which of those ways is the answer you'll accept?

So, if I understand correctly, the closer told me that asking for solution of problem that can have multiple solutions is *too broad*. And this is strictly against things I see in wild - there are tons of answers comparising pros/cons of different solutions.

Comment: It's possible for a question to be too broad if it has *too many* solutions. If I tried to ask how to create a "Hello World" program but said I didn't care which language it was in that would be an example of a question with two many possible answers. A question isn't too broad because there's only three possible solutions.

Comment: It has been reopened by a gold badger, meanwhile. I edited the text a little to remove the UPDATE headers. Stack Overflow keeps the edit history, you should avoid holding an update log in your question. It falls in the category "fluff".

Comment: If you know there might be more than one solution, it certainly *helps* if you provide some criteria for selecting "the" solution – be it terseness, performance, readability, etc. Asking a question with more than one solution seems not wrong per-se, but it is hard to know whether the asker is actually fine with all of them or just did not care to specify.

Comment: There's nothing with asking a question that can have multiple solutions; often askers are not even be aware there are (significantly) different ways of achieve the same result. If, however, you are aware there are multiple solutions, or have found a solution you don't like, then you need to define the parameters of the solution you are looking for; shortest code, perhaps, or most performant (which would need clarification on what that is). If you have a solution explain *why* it doesn't fit your criteria, as otherwise any new answers could end up more or less duplicating that solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Breaking down "too broad" and trying to understand it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it)

Comment: see also [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: @gnat I never asked "Is it possible to:", I asked for ways to "Create lambda over given method that injects first paramater". It is concrete problem that may have more than one solution, and at the same time may benefit community (ie. it is crucial for script-hand-wiring in C# - which is my case, actually)

Comment: [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/64383835/1) of discussed question reads like that to me, "Is there any way I can etc"

Comment: @gnat - yeah, I fixed that after getting asked in comments to clarify. Still a comment is nicer than nuking the question out :-)

Comment: @gnat: "Is it possible to" is definitely a warning sign.  So is "what have you tried."  But you have temper that with context.  You already know what my usual response is to "is it possible to."  This isn't one of those cases.

Comment: wrt commenting instead of nuking, consider giving a read to [How long should we wait for a poster to clarify a question before closing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260265/839601)

Comment: @gnat Okay, I see your point. It wasn't that way when I joined the site, through :)

Comment: Wanted to throw in that the *vast, vast majority* of programming problems that are scoped larger than "*explain how `funcX()` works*" will have multiple ways to approach the problem, and thus multiple solutions. One of the whole points of having the format we do on SO is to allow and encourage multiple answers to questions, which would be pointless if all Q's were expected to have one, single, definitive, "best" solution.

Comment: The mere presence of the phrase "is there any way..." does not mean a question is too broad. If I ask "Is there any way to fix my problem" that's broad. If I ask "Is there any way to prevent XYZ compiler from outputting specific message ABC under conditions 123" that's not broad at all, it's extremely narrow.

Comment: I had also posted a question describing my problem with 3 solutions I used and their pros and cons, and I asked concretely for any other solution if any that can be used. But mine got downvoted, and closed and bot even deleted it without my permission. Hypocricy! This was my question > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065166/how-to-maintain-two-versions-of-same-entity-available-for-edit-simultaneously-wi

Comment: Is there a problem that only has one solution? I'm not aware of that problem.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

> Asking "is there any possible way?" just isn't on topic here; it's way too broad

No, it isn't.  Your particular problem is sufficiently specified.

There are hordes of questions asked on Stack Overflow that are incomplete, under-specified or otherwise don't contain enough information to make them answerable.  We should be focusing on closing *those* questions.  Yours is not one of those, and the close voters simply lack enough imagination to see that.

Unfortunately, for years we have been pushing Stack Overflow into becoming a troubleshooting tool, a strict problem/answer pattern matching exercise.  I know why this has happened; it is because of the hordes.  This strictness isn't necessarily a bad thing.
Unfortunately that doesn't leave much room for creativity, and your problem requires a creative solution.  It requires that someone actually *think* about the problem and work out ways in which that problem might be solved with a novel approach.

> If I come up with (for example) three different ways to accomplish the final goal, how am I to know which of those ways is the answer you'll accept?

To that person, I would say: *post your proposed solution and find out.*

The most interesting questions on Stack Overflow are not the "fix my broken code" questions; they are the "how to" questions.  These are the ones that will endure, not the troubleshooting ones.  If a "how to" question contains sufficient information to make it answerable in a few paragraphs, then by definition it is not too broad.

What we should be looking for in "Too Broad" are questions like "Teach me how to write a `for` loop," or "recommend a library."

Closing as a dupe to that other question only tells you why your particular approach doesn't work; it doesn't suggest a new approach.

Comment: I had also posted a question describing my problem with 3 solutions I used and their pros and cons, and I asked concretely for any other solution if any that can be used. But mine got downvoted, and closed and bot even deleted it without my permission. Hypocricy! This was my question > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065166/how-to-maintain-two-versions-of-same-entity-available-for-edit-simultaneously-wi

Comment: Technically, “is there any possible way?” is not a “how to” question but a “yes or no” question.

Comment: @Holger Yes, we should simply rename all questions "Is there..." "Can one..." into "How to" because that is the question that is underlying all of these. Programmers are not mathematicians. They don't just want to know about the existence of a solution, the also want the solution, unless no solution exists, in which case a plausible proof-like non-existence answer is needed. "How to" basically asks for that all.

Comment: Especially true since there are plenty of (most?) computing problems that have more than one valid solution - which one the OP (or some subsequent reader) picks as "best" is based on many considerations including some not even mentioned in the question.  (I frequently post answers - or comments - proposing a "different" approach - just to show that there are many ways of looking at a problem and many solutions that can be considered precisely depending on these other characteristics.) (Many times these other considerations are _real world issues_ which many on this site distain ...)

Comment: w.r.t. "Post your proposed solution and find out" - yes!  Except my attitude is more like:  Why not post your proposed solution _for the good of the OP and subsequent readers_ and who cares about whether you get the green check mark or not?  If your solution is valuable - let us know, even if the OP has other ideas.

Comment: @davidbak Absolutely! Alternate solutions are part of what makes Stack Overflow work. It's awesome if the accepted answer worked for the OP, but it's even more awesome when answer #2(or even #7!) happens to be exactly what I needed because it more closely matches my own approach to the same problem.

Answer (score 10):

"Is it possible to..." questions [are controversial](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question). There are typically two ways to interpret this kind of question: either as a straightforward "yes or no?" question that tends not to invite further explanation or learning, or as "how do I do *x*?" question. The latter kind of questions is mostly problematic if it's unclear or "gimme teh codez." I really don't think that either is the case for your question, since you indicate what you tried and what your point of confusion is.

Also, having multiple possible answers (or even having numerous possible answers) isn't necessarily a problem, unless it's due to the problem being insufficiently constrained. (I think your question is sufficiently constrained, though). In practice, many (or even most) non-trivial programming problems have multiple possible solutions, so as long as the question contains enough detail to know what kind of a solution you'd find acceptable having multiple possible answers is just fine.

Another good heuristic: would an answerer be able to tell whether the answer they wrote answers the question? And would a voter be able to know based on the queston which answers to upvote and which ones to downvote?

Finally, this doesn't really apply to your question, but [questions that invite low-quality answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) (e.g. "suggest me some tutorials where I can learn quick") are usually off topic.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure why many here say this is an "is it possible to..." question. Clearly they haven't actually read your question.

I don't have a lot to say other than this: if your question has become "controversial" then SO has evolved beyond a point even I do not fully understand, nor support.

A well-written question that has a *specific* question - *how do I create a (delegate|callback|whatever) in a syntactically concise way* - that even a C#-er like me can understand should never be considered off topic.

Further, you provided your own answers giving thorough information. **This is precisely what this website was built for** and this method of knowledge sharing was expressly *encouraged* at one point in time.

Glad to see it's been (correctly) re-opened.

Comment: SO controls itself. If the average quality of a user is low, then the quality control will also be low. It's probably some kind of feedback mechanism.

Answer (score -4):

I think it is not

1. You might be looking for more efficient solution
2. More elegant one
3. A solution using different library
4. You may not want to use a specific kinda algorithm for various reasons
5. You may not want to use standard libraries, but want to implement on your own.

Or for another reason.

So, as long as you clarify why/how your question is different from existing question, I think it is not a duplicate.

Comment: The question asked here was *not* whether it's a duplicate.

Comment: @CodyGray, seems I didn't read properly. Thanks for clarification