# "Community" bot deleted my reopened question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, deleted-questions, community-user, automatic-deletion

**What happened?**

Yesterday, my question got undeleted. And obviously, undeleting a question requires reopening votes, that this question would surely have received. This means **the voters should have agreed that the question is NOT opinion-based or too broad.**

While this all happened, my question had a downvote and yesterday the question got a month old. (It took an entire month to clear the queues and got reopened). Now "community" bot's everyday deletion criteria is

> Question gets deleted, If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> 1. has −1 or lower score
> 2. has no answers
> 3. is not locked

The question that was just reopened was redeleted because of this [automated algorithm that runs every day](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) on above-stated criteria. My reopened question might not even have got enough visibility after getting reopened altogether.

**Therefore, I appeal to reopen my question back AND add another condition in the automated algorithm to not delete a reopened question at least for a certain time.** There is no point in reopening a (deleted) question that would get deleted back in just one day without giving it enough visibility or waiting period (I had thought to add bounty after waiting for a day or two).

**About my question**

I had asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065166/how-to-maintain-two-versions-of-same-entity-available-for-edit-simultaneously-wi) question that was misunderstood as an inappropriate question and got deleted. I had appealed for reopening of my question by making an edit in question and clarifying the fact that my question is NOT opinion-based or too broad because my question describes the solutions that I am aware of/tried with pros and cons of each and I am looking for any other solution(s) that can be applied to the given (specific) problem.

Then just at around that same time, a meta thread discussed exactly the same topic about whether [asking for solutions to a problem that has more than one possible solution too broad for SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402142/is-asking-for-solutions-to-a-problem-that-has-more-than-one-possible-solution-to). This thread response's accepted answer says, ["No, it isn't"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402153/2828434). I made another edit to my question and included this thread's link as well.

Yesterday, it got undeleted and today bot redeleted it.

I am also open to discussion and clearing my understanding about what else can be improved in my question if it still is considered a misfit.

Comment: [Screenshot for <10k users](https://i.imgur.com/fssyL9E.png)

Comment: *"And obviously, undeleting a question requires reopening votes..."* No, it doesn't. Where did you get this impression? Closure and deletion are two separate actions.

Comment: @CodyGray [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFzoI.png) says that it requires 5 votes to reopen a question.

Comment: It says it requires 5 votes to *undelete* the post. It says nothing about reopening (which only requires 3 votes, just as closing requires 3 votes).

Comment: Is undeleting and reopening different? Wouldn't undeleting reopen the question?

Comment: That question is a design problem, not a programming problem. Did you consider checking if it would fit on SoftwareEngineering.se?

Comment: No, a question can be either open or closed, deleted or undeleted. Those are different states. There are open+deleted questions, and and closed+non-deleted questions. Neither can receive answers, logically. But the deleted questions cannot receive comments and are generally hidden from view.

Comment: Ohh!! Thanks for clarifying this. I didn't know that these all are different states. My bad. @rene sure I'll try asking once on SoftwareEngineering.se

Comment: @VLAZ This is off-topic but how are the comment replies indented like that? Is that a userscript?

Comment: You're unlucky with the timing. IIRC RemoveDeadQuestions runs once a week. You should have waited another day so it would had a window of 7 days to gather an upvote. But if no viewers find that question useful it will roomba again next week. Or  it must get an answer in that period.

Comment: The confusion arose when I received [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdgV7.png) notification yesterday that said my question is **reopened** and when I checked back, it was actually **undeleted** ! So I am still confused was my question never **closed** but **deleted** , and when it got **undelete** , the notification said it **reopened** ? :D

Comment: [It was undeleted by you and two other users, then it was reopened by one of the undelete voters and a moderator, and then it was deleted by Community](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMuQ2.png). So, yeah, I think there might be a reasonable feature request in here to consider recent activity (such as reopening) when running the Roomba. Otherwise, this makes for a pretty confusing user experience. (And a very pointless reopen.)

Comment: @Karan You may check the [Revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64065166/revisions) of the post (or the [Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64065166/timeline) for more details). Over the past two months, your question was closed, then deleted, then undeleted, then reopened, and then deleted again the next day by the Roomba.

Comment: Thanks @41686d6564. That clears it all. Undelete and Reopened both happened on the same day, leading to confusion, And when I got the notification for reopening, i thought it actually meant undelete. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray, yes if possible please consider that.

Comment: @41686d6564 apologies for the late reply. Yes, it's a userscript [threaded-comments](https://stackapps.com/questions/2050/threaded-comments). I'd recommend it - it's pretty good. Do note that occasionally it messes up when there are a lot of comments and people don't necessarily @-mention each other when responding. There is an option to toggle threading per comment section, so if it *is* messy, you can see it normally.

Comment: It does seem like this scenario is counter-productive to the messaging asking a user to improve their question. The downvotes usually come in when the question is in a pre-edit state, and people don't often remember to come back and clean that up if the asker has taken the time to clean their post up. This combination of events would be very easy for a bad first-time post to fall into this very trap and discourage a new user.

Comment: Related MSE suggestion about the same problem: [If a Roomba-deleted question gets undeleted, please make it exempt from its next runs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359643/259412)

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid cases similar to this in the future, I suggest making the following changes to the roomba process and to the Community user's actions in general:

- **Reopening questions should reset the roomba timer.** Questions that get reopened have often been improved, so the community needs to have time to reevaluate the question. I won't expand on this too much, I think the question has done a good job explaining why this is needed.
- **Questions should only roomba once.** Only moderators and >20k users can undelete questions that have roobmad (the OP can cast one undelete vote, but the question still needs more undelete votes to be undeleted). If a question that has roombad has been undeleted, it's clear that either a moderator or two trusted users (three if the OP hasn't voted to undelete) don't think the question should be deleted. I think that it's in general a bad idea to have a robot undo the actions of humans who are trusted to know what they're doing.
- **The Community user should only protect a given question once.** This isn't about roomba, but it's related to my point above so I thought I would put it here anyway. As I said above, I don't think robots should undo the actions of humans who are trusted to know  what they're doing. This applies to deletion, but also to protection (and to any other action, but deletion and protection are the only ones I could think of that apply to the Community user). This isn't as important as for deletion since protected questions are often popular and will often eventually get unprotected manually anyway, but I still think it's counter-productive to have the Community user undo the actions of a trusted human.

Comment: I agree with all of this except the part about only protecting a question once: the situation that resulted in a question being auto-protected could reoccur, and protection isn't nearly as problematic as incorrect deletion.

Comment: @RyanM I agree that protection isn't very problematic, but if a moderator or high-reputation user manually unprotected it there is usually a reason. In most cases the question will never get unprotected, but in the rare cases where a trusted human decides that a question shouldn't be protected I don't think a robot should be able to undo that.

Comment: @RyanM I'd say automatic re-protection causes more problems than it's worth. On the global meta, the past contest posts have caused protracted protect/unprotect wars between Community and users.

Answer (score -32):

In my opinion this issue can easily be solved by the developers if they add a new rule to the roomba script, namely:

#### Any activity on a question or its answers should reset the roomba timer

This includes answers, comments, edits, upvotes, downvotes, close-reopen, delete-undelete votes, etc.

The original purpose was to remove "dead-end" questions, if it's still active, it should not be deleted.

Comment: Downvotes, delete and close votes reset the roomba timer? That doesn't seem effective. Neither comments resetting the timer, but that I could at least understand.

Comment: Any reason to include *any* activity? It seems like only actions indicating positive reactions – e.g. reopen, upvote – should make content eligible for preservation. Having negative actions count seems counterproductive.

Comment: At least we can agree that users casting **undelete** votes should reset roomba's timer. Totally. /s

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: That could make sense, but it's not like there is a real hurry to delete the question either. The vast majority of questions on SO quickly end up in a "dead" state, with few if any interactions after the first hours.

Comment: @yivi: Why the `/s`? This is exactly the scenario that happened to OP, his question got undeleted, but then roomda  deleted it again within the day.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right if you see it that way. But with the exception of the vote that actually undeletes a question, all the other undelete votes happen to be in a question where roomba is irrelevant, since the question is already deleted. Using the undelete vote as a reference to reset the timer doesn't seem practical. Simply: if a question was recently undeleted, it could have its "timer" reset, as it is. Not sure I find it entirely practical either. Any question that was recently undeleted should get some action soonish to or go back to torpor.

Comment: @yivi: Yes that seems simpler

Comment: undelete and reopen. These 2 activities should be enough

Comment: The criteria already includes "has no answers", so answers wouldn't factor into this (unless it was posted and deleted, but that should be rare enough to ignore). "It received no positive interaction for 30 days and someone downvoted it" seems like a good enough reason to delete it, regardless of *when* the downvote came. I might add a week (but probably not reset it entirely) after a comment or closure / edit to give OP or others a chance to edit / give others a chance to upvote or answer. Partial closure or deletion votes is unlikely to lead to any action that could save the question.

Comment: @user000001 I interpret "casting undelete votes" to mean the question is not yet undeleted.

Comment: @BernhardBarker: True, only the final undelete vote matters. My idea was that as long as *anybody* is still interested in the question, it should not be auto-deleted **yet**. It doesn't escape the roomba, just borrows some time, which could potentially save it. Regarding the exception for downvotes, I am not against it, just not convinced that it is strictly necessary. Now that people have already voted though, it wouldn't be fair for me to alter the message of this post.

Comment: @yivi: It's a first approximation. Feel free to write a more refined answer. As is, it still would be a better change than not changing it.

Comment: No @Joshua, it would be worse. To cover for a an edge case we would be making roomba much less effective. Better not change it than change it like this. I’m not particularly convinced  about the need for a change. It’s an edge case, and can be managed by the user (flagging, reposting, etc).

Comment: @yivi: Flagging will not help, unless the moderator upvotes the post above zero, or locks it. Reposting counts against the user's question limit.

Comment: Flagging. A mod can undelete and the question will get another week of life before is deleted again. That's enough. Question limit: this is and edge case of and edge case, since it only affects users that are close to the question limit. And in those cases, well, if the original question was roomba-deleted and it's likely reposting it will not go that awesome either, so it's fine that it counts against that limit.

Comment: And since you are worried about that edge case, you need to consider that your proposal of making close-delete-down votes extend the question shelf life will probably expose the question to more downvotes, which might impact users that are close to the question ban threshold.