# How many times has the roomba overriden human votes?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, statistics, vote-to-undelete, automatic-deletion

As most readers here probably already know, there is a script that automatically deletes questions based on some criteria, known as the [roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) script.

But this meta-question: [“Community” bot deleted my reopened question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403049/community-bot-deleted-my-reopened-question), highlighted an interesting case where roomba automatically deleted a question that been explicitly marked for undeletion by human voters.

This seems to be a case of [priority inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion), where the script always wins in the end, unless the score of the question changes enough during this small interim until the next execution.

So this raised a question in my mind: How many times has this happened on Stack Overflow? Is this something that only happens rarely, or do most roomba-deleted-and-then-undeleted questions end up being deleted again, with the script nullifying valid votes from humans?

The data points I am looking for are in a given time-frame:

1. Number of questions posted
2. Number of questions deleted by roomba
3. Number of questions deleted by roomba that where undeleted at a later time at least once
4. Number of questions deleted by roomba that where undeleted at a later time at least once, and then deleted by roomba again.

Comment: i wished, that the script would tell me which questions was deleted. i see only when i loose points agan 10 or 15, that some questions hits the bucket

Comment: @nbk: Yes what you described is painful, but it's a different situation than what I am talking about. This is not about the *upvotes* that are deleted when the question is deleted, but about undelete votes cast by users with more than 10k reputation to restore a question that was wrongly deleted. Under some circumstances these undelete votes are cancelled be the roomba script.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to get you the answers to these questions. For this, you would need an SE developer to run some data mining.

Comment: @Dharman: It's simple sql queries, shog9 would have the data in 3 minutes if he was still around, oh well.

Comment: @user000001 3 mins? rene can have it only 1min .. he's probably doing it right now ;) (edit: I guess we don't have access to deleted queston using SEDE so no luck here ...)

Comment: ^ you can probably get the (3)  using SEDE considering the fact that the community user is the one deleting the question when the roomba strike

Comment: I wonder if the people downvoting disagree with this data being presented, or if the're just not interested in the topic.

Comment: I downvoted because I am not interested in this data, I doubt we can ever get accurate data, and I really think this is not going to benefit anyone. Let deleted questions be deleted, and instead focus more on deleting other questions.

Comment: I remember I've noticed a few times on a site I moderate, especially due to the 1-year pruning on 0-score questions (aka `RemoveAbandonedQuestions`); I undeleted it, then it was roomba'd again the week after, until I had to upvote it to prevent being roomba'd. The moral of the story is: forget the undeletion, the questions themselves have to get out from roomba's condition first.

Comment: please consider changing tags from discussion to [meta-tag:support] and somehow adding tag [meta-tag:statistics]

Comment: *roomba automatically deleted a question that been explicitly marked for undeletion by human voters.* No, it does not. Roomba deletes questions with no score. If the superior humans that undeleted the question didn't deem the question upvote worthy then I state that humans didn't care for that question. It was deleted rightfully, again. Don't lump two unrelated events together and then blame the event you don't like for being wrong. The humans are wrong, the roomba is fine.

Comment: @rene: I agree that we should always upvote questions we think should be reopened, but you should consider the case where the initial score was so low, that even if all the undelete voters did upvote, it wouldn't have made a difference. Also the first two undelete voters see the question in a deleted state, so they cannot upvote the question until later, if they remember to check in time.

Comment: @rene: Also is Temani correct in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403071/how-many-times-has-the-roomba-overriden-human-votes#comment809851_403071) about SEDE? I remember reading somewhere that some aggregated and anonymized data about deleted questions was included in SEDE, but would that be enough to create an answer?

Comment: This is the best I can do for now. https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1335947?start=2019-11-01&end=2020-11-01 you can't really know if roomba is the reason for deletion. There are 4 resultsets, matching each of your bullets. Result 4 returns 0 records, that can't be right but I'm a bit short on time so maybe someone spots what I screwed up there. Otherwise I'll revisit later to see if I can rectify that.

Comment: @user000001 a question needs a positive score to keep the roomba away. Are we really making all this fuss for that one question that got deleted at -3 and no one else was bothered to vote on it?

Comment: @rene: The intention was not to create a fuss, I am sorry if I did, the reason for this post is that I answered the linked question, and people in the comments claimed that this was an extremely rate scenario, which is why I wanted so see if it was true.

Comment: I would argue: we don't delete enough which causes that the voters that upvote anything you show them only vote on mediocre stuff because there is plenty of that. It is easy to get an upvote, it is hard to get a downvote. Once it is time to feed the roomba, it is too late. 30 days without attention / votes, why should we care? Rare or not, it is still value we didn't deem upvote worthy. Asking how that question could have prevented that faith with a better title, tag or body would be useful. Preventing the inevitable is not.

Comment: @nbk *Every* user can see their own recently (within 60 days) deleted questions and answers. There's a "recently deleted {questions|answers}" link at the bottom of the tabs in your profile which separately show your questions and answers (i.e. not the summary). For you, that's [recently deleted questions](//stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/5193536) and [recently deleted answers](//stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/5193536) (these pages are only viewable by you and moderators). With >10k rep, you can also search for *your own* deleted Qs & As with `deleted:1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't exactly answer that question based on the public available data.

This is what we have to work with

- Table PostsWithDeleted can tell us if a post is deleted or not (deletiondate will be non null)
- Table Votes will hold deletion votes (votetypeid  = 10) for all posts (including deleted posts)
- Table Votes will hold undeletion votes (votetypeid  = 11) for all posts (including deleted posts)

There is no record for a roomba event, let alone that an history record is kept (the posthistory table only has records for non-deleted posts).

The roomba script runs at either 00:00 or 03:00 UTC. We can use that knowledge to workout if a question was deleted due to roomba by looking at the deletion time. We might have false positives there but in the grand scale of things that is within the  margin of error.

This is the best I can come up with for the period between 2019-11-01 and 2020-11-01:

```
questions | roomba | undeleted | deleted_again 
----------|--------|-----------|-------------- 
1148092   | 709520 | 46928     | 1817
```

Undeleted is the number of questions that were undeleted in that same timeframe.
Deleted again are question that are currently roomba-ed but have an undelete record in the votes table, ever.

For science here is a link [to the actual query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1336171?start=2019-11-01&end=2020-11-01&opt.textResults=true)

Answer (score 2):

A rough guess: a very small number of questions. Questions deleted by roomba are rarely improved or undeleted.

I base it on the sole premise of how roomba works. It deletes questions that have been closed for a while. If someone would improve the question then it would likely happen during the time the question was visible. Cases when the question is improved while deleted tend to mostly happen when OP gets question-banned and wants to get out of the ban. Without meta help, the chances of such question getting a second chance are very minimal.

What complicates this further is that deletion is a quiet action. Unless OP was paying close attention then they would likely not notice that the question got deleted.

If the question was improved sufficiently then it should go through the reopen review and get reopened. If it wasn't closed then the matter is a little more difficult as someone would have to find it, reevaluate, and upvote if the question is now useful.

Unless you are question-banned or close to getting banned, then it's probably easier to leave deleted questions in their grave and write a different question instead.

Comment: Ok, but two things, 1) my ultimate motivation was understand to the ratio 3/4, ie if it's pointless to undelete roomba questions. 2) reopening is not always sufficient, roomba can delete open question is some cases

Comment: Also this doesn't really answer the question quantitatively so I will not accept this answer at this time.