# How can I improve my question to make it more focused?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I asked a question about Azure App Services and if it's possible to manually set them to idle.

[How can I manually unload an Azure App Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66225050/how-can-i-manually-unload-an-azure-app-service)

Somebody voted to close the question because they felt it was unfocused, and the question is now closed.
The help text says this regarding posts that need more focus:

> This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

So I'm dumbfounded as to how I can edit my *single question* post to adhere to this text more correctly.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: You've answered the title of this Meta question in the body :) Asking for feedback on Meta is a perfectly reasonable way to figure out how to improve a Main post to make it on-topic.

Comment: How have I answered my question in the body?

Comment: “Needs more focus” is the new “too broad”. See [Breaking down "too broad"/"needs more focus" and trying to understand it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258589/4642212) for more context.

Comment: No, I meant the title of the Meta post. I edited the comment, as it was a bit unclear.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Ok...?  So how is my question too broad?  The answer to my question is either "No, it's not possible - your only option is to wait the 20 minutes until the app service is unloaded automatically" or it's "Yes, you can trigger the app service to go idle by doing (some procedure)".  And in any case I don't think my question is neither unfocused or too broad.

Comment: I don't think the question is too broad, but it took me reading it a few times to actually realize what your goal with the question is (or, i guess, what i think the goal is.) Maybe that's due to my in-experience with azure, but it couldn't hurt for the question to be a bit more organized. TLDR it appears as though for debugging reasons, you want to cause the unloading to happen on demand rather than needing to wait for the app to idle for 20 min

Comment: The commenters also appear to be missing that aspect of your question

Comment: Are you looking answers that explain which buttons to push, an api call, a powershell/cli thingy, something else?  It might help to clarify that as well. And I suggest to scope-down, so pick one of those options.

Comment: @KevinB You're absolutely right, Kevin.  That was my intention.  Unfortunately I feel asking a question on SO is a real balancing act.  If I just ask the question, I get flak for not providing context.  But if I provide all the details, then I get flak for not being concise enough.  It's almost impossible to please all the people with "downvote" and "close" votes. </whine>

Comment: Try focusing more on the "manually unloading" bit and not the "my app doesn't function properly" bit if you want the focus to be on manually unloading. It is somewhat of an X/Y question, but not so much that i think it's a problem

Comment: @rene I think that would indicate that I believe I know of a way that this could be done.  But I have no idea if this is possible to do and how.  Also, I'm not an enormously experienced Azure user, and I don't know all the features that Azure has.  I did search for quite a while before asking the question, though, and I got nowhere closer to learning an answer to this other than finding that GitHub issue that I included in my post.

Comment: I've added some more information in my question.  Hopefully that will make it more clear.

Answer (score 8):

I don't expect there are a ton of options to unload an app service, even if we include *it cannot be done* so I don't really see how that question is too broad.

I've checked the proposed duplicate and at best that helps if you **do not** want to unload the app service, ever. That is the opposite of what you asked for unless I miss something. I've left a comment for the user that offered that duplicate.

I made a minor edit to set the actual question apart from the context.

The only thing I can imagine is, people wonder what approach you expect to be using to unload the app service. Most things can be done multiple ways, either via the Web GUI or via Azure CLI tools. Maybe pick one you feel most comfortable with and ask for that. Azure is a tool often used by software developers so using Azure is on-topic, even if it is by the Web UI.

I've cast a re-open vote to get the question into the re-open queue. Let's see how that ends.