# This is why you don't answer "how do I do this" with absolutely no attempt shown at solving

Tags: discussion, bounty, scope

Since [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893913/how-to-create-a-spreadsheet-out-of-an-existing-spreadsheet) got answered instead of being downvoted to oblivion and closed it slipped through *unnoticed*...

Now, this:

1. teaches/demonstrates a really bad practice for newcomers; [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23143872/how-to-vlookup-a-combination-of-cells), [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363464/how-to-split-a-table-in-excel-vba)
2. there is a bounty to reward an answer but the answer shouldn't have been there in the first place ([I am basing my off-topic reason as per No. 3 in the help-centre](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252697/remove-or-update-point-3-from-help-center-off-topic-list))
3. you can't vote to close this question(*even if it's a duplicate*) as it's bounty protected ( *even though you may try to flag it for moderators attention but [those are usually declined anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252539/flagging-a-suspected-off-topic-question-protected-by-a-bounty)* )

Note: *just in case you have not noticed the bounty does not come from the OP but someone else*.

I get a feeling that offering a bounty on your absolutely no-effort shown question gives you an immunity from getting your question closed - it's attracting rep-whores and therefore you will nearly 90% of the time get an answer anyway.

What can we do to prevent this from happening? Should we even bother or just let this slip through and then in a month, year or two wonder WTF has happened to this site?

Comment: There are *lots* of no-effort questions being answered every day, sometimes with high-quality answers we do want to keep around. Do you really think having to wait for a few days before closing such questions is putting the site at risk?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi well, [someone is constantly trying to delete this(*in fact is has been deleted before)*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19881863/how-to-use-comparison-methods-between-class-object-modules-in-vba-in-a-similar-m) because no-effort from the OP aka. unclear what you're asking as the easiest way to get a question closed and [they don't care that the answer itself is quite good.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212077/removed-question-is-it-possible-to-see-the-history-of-changes). How do you explain that?

Comment: Maybe that someone is thinking deleting the question will "punish" the answerer. I actually considered doing that when it became obvious answering such questions was part of our quality problem, and even did it a couple of times, but finally decided against it because it would go against the primary goal of the site, especially when the answers are good.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Ok I see. So according to your logic we should allow all the questions based on quality of answers and not worry about the questions at all. Allow all questions quality (and possible duplicates) except spam etc? Just over a year ago  that definitely **wasn't** the goal of SO. The quality has dropped, and instead of curing the problem SE and its community seems to just accept it... sad.

Comment: That's not quite what I said. The question should not be "allowed", it should be closed. And possibly downvoted. But *not* deleted, considering the answer it has received. Same for yours.

Answer (score 25):

Wait a second, I want to make sure I've got this right ...

We run a Q&A site, where people ask and answer questions, and you want to introduce some kind of rule that says you should only answer certain types of questions otherwise face ridicule from the community?

## Hogwash.

The person that answered it (and it is a *very* good answer) found the question and the problem interesting enough to spend some time creating something of lasting value. ***Stop reading anything else into it.*** It's *not* creating any kind of self-fulfilling prophecy that ends in us all burning in unstable unicorn tears.

It's *not* a stellar question, it doesn't encapsulate any kind of effort but it *does* somewhat clearly articulate the problem at hand. If I was trying to do the same thing, I'd now know how to do it. It doesn't encapsulate a lot of effort because the person just *did not know where to begin*, and is obviously working around a language barrier. It's not a horrible question.

Now before you get all mad at me and stuff, *I'm not discounting or dismissing the problem*. I realize you're not talking about *just* this question, it's not quite representative of the *really* smelly variety. To that, we have a task force working on it. That's:

- Myself
- Shog
- Jay Hanlon
- David Fullerton
- Jarrod Dixon

... and other developers as needed. Joel is also *very* involved. Part of our goal, which we discussed in-depth yesterday until the wee hours of the morning is doing a better job of identifying questions that *could* be great with a little more effort, and getting them some love *before* they get much visibility.

Such a system would have made that question better. It would also do a *much* better job of making sure that the *truly* hopeless stuff never makes it to the front page, while helping to ensure the really good stuff doesn't meet with much delay.

That's just *one* thing we're doing, including complete overhaul of the question blocks, [combating recidivism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234517/why-have-i-been-barred-from-posting-questions/234518#234518) in very abusive cases and (channeling Billy Mays here a bit) ***but wait, there's more!***

Some meta posts will be going out starting this week *as* we make progress on this and have new things to show, or need some input to help make something saner, better or perhaps even unnecessary through better design.

***Don't go looking to unofficial, difficult to discover and seemingly weird 'conventions' in the community to solve this, that's just going to backfire.***

Give us a chance to fix this, and fix it *right* before resorting to that. If you see a question you can answer, go ahead and answer it. If it smells, *fix it first, if you can* - it's that simple. We've *finally* just about got something designed that will handle quality at our now *massive* scale, and that wasn't / isn't an easy problem to tackle.

Comment: hahahah hilarious.... very good answer??? yeah right. *`It doesn't encapsulate a lot of effort because the person just did not know where to begin,`* OK, consider: "how do I write a new C+#+ programming language? I just dont know where to begin". *`getting them some love`* - No, please no more "Summer of love". *`Some meta posts will be going out starting this week `* and *`Give us a chance to fix this, and fix it right`* looking forward to it...or maybe not?

Comment: @mehow "How do I write a new programming language?" is hardly comparable to "How do I do something with a spreadsheet". And by 'love' I meant editing. If you're able to answer a question, you _should_ be able to clarify it through edits. I know what you're saying, but honestly, all that's coming through is frustration and hostility. That's not going to help anything, maybe take a break.

Comment: *"Give us a chance to fix this"* - Lol... The track record indicates Stack Overflow can't seem to identify and fix problems. I'm guessing the [new question wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373030/608639) is going to take 3 years to complete (if it ever arrives). In the meantime, thanks for acknowledging there's an increasing problem with off-topic garbage dating back to 2012 or 2013.

Answer (score 7):

It's not new that a good answer can rescue an otherwise bad question. Jeff called it [optimizing for pearls, not sand](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). There's a [gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/95/reversal) for providing an excellent answer to a terrible question:

> [image: Reversal]  Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score

**Conspiring to leave open questions (no matter how poor they are) unanswered has never been a goal of the site.** In fact we pride ourselves on having an exceptionally high answer rate. We achieve that by closing questions that can't really be answered. As you point out, this question *can't* be closed because of the outstanding bounty, which is by design. It's also an edge case for a bounty to be offered on a poor question. Perhaps that should be [corrected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107282/1438).

> What can we do to prevent this from happening?

**Close questions earlier.** This is why [burning down the close queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251489/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) matters at all. In the case of *this particular question*, however, nobody voted to close when the question came up in February, nor when it was answered (twice), nor (for obvious reasons) when it slipped into obscurity and nobody noticed. As far as I can tell, the first time anyone considered closing was when the bounty was offered *to reward an existing answer*. Forgive me for saying this, but that strikes me as a case of [sour grapes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fox_and_the_Grapes).

Closing questions is a scalable solution to preserving our expert answering resources. [Moderation at scale](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling) is the only thing that makes it possible to have a site that helps as many people as Stack Overflow does. So we absolutely need to close (and eventually delete) questions that waste the time of our top users. Closing relieves them of the responsibility of providing an answer.

> Should we even bother or just let this slip through and then in a month, year or two wonder WTF has happened to this site?

You are suggesting a [slippery slope](http://www.fallacyfiles.org/slipslop.html) argument, which could totally be legitimate if the steps are few and the causual connection between steps is strong. In this case, I don't think the connections are particularly strong. Lots of questions slip under the radar with no ill effects. I've yet to see any evidence that the [broken window theory applies to question closing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258263/does-the-broken-window-theory-apply-to-closing-questions).

Stack Overflow has a hard-earned reputation for being a good place to get programming questions answered. It seems like we ought to pursue other avenues before sacrificing that reputation.

Comment: still missing the point here... the question is off-topic according to the site rule no.3 - Minimal understanding ,attempted solutions etc. While [I have asked for it to be removed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252697/remove-point-3-from-help-center-off-topic-list) as it is misleading - still nothing has been done about it. IMHO, the question is off-topic. The downvotes have nothing to do with answering - you're cool to answer even a -200 downvotes question as long as it's on topic. This one was off-topic according to the no. 3 rule. Yeah... it's that simple.

Comment: To your slippery slope argument, I would certainly understand that being the case that a failed attempt at moderating one question doesn't doom the entire site to failure, but when [the community fails to recognize that a failure occurred in this instance](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261631/1159478) that *is* a strong indication of a larger problem.  The fact that so many people think that *nothing bad happened here* is exactly why we know that this bad thing is going to happen more and more often.

Comment: And as to your point on the broken windows theory, there's a difference between stating that removing low quality content doesn't stop everyone from posting more low quality content and using that to conclude that we should just stop even trying to get rid of low quality content.  Even if someone coming to the site for the first time won't realize that their questions aren't good enough (or even know that there's a standard), if the site is well moderated they'll learn after a question or two.  If we keep answering these posts then the same users keep asking them, over and over.