# Is the “Ask a question” wizard being used?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

I have a question about [“Ask a question” wizard prototype](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369682/608639). The question is, is the wizard being used for new users? Or is the problem still being studied?

If not being used, then can something please be moved into service to help curb the off-topic fodder? Preferably some that puts *"Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions"* in NEON lights.

I'm struggling to understand how questions like [My Ubuntu 18 system is annoyingly slow and taking 15 minutes to boot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52007297/608639) and [Ubuntu 18.04 - missing 'lowerdir'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52006890/608639) are (still?) being asked at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Do you *really* think that a wizard will stop people from asking bad questions if that is their intent?

Comment: @Makoto - I don't know. I don't know what controls are in place to stop the flow (*q.v.*). If there is no control in place then the first step is to add a control. I work in software security. When we identify a gap the first thing we do is place a security control to contain it. I'm not clear if the same process is in place at Stack Overflow.

Comment: After that wizard people still gonna ask bad questions. It's up to user or on their intent of asking.

Comment: Thanks @amku91. *"After that wizard..."* -  does that mean the wizard is being used? Or are you offering your opinion for what you believe the outcome will be?

Comment: I mean, [I suggested that there be a control](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358265/1079354) in lieu of the wizard, but I don't think they wanted to implement that with this.

Comment: Yup. But problem is behind of that type of question is either user want  someone else to do his work or user don't know how to search problem on net . My ubuntu question. @jww First case is ok. But what about second case ?

Comment: @amku91 - Yup what? Are you offering your opinion or is the control being used?

Comment: Control being used. @jww

Comment: @Makoto If that is their *intent*? I doubt many people come here with the *intent* to ask bad questions. I've asked several bad questions, but that was never my intent. It simply requires a lot of effort (perhaps even practice) to draft a high quality, non-duplicate question.

Comment: @Sinjai:  If you come to Stack Overflow with a question about why you can't install an application on your phone or your desktop...I'm not sure what your intent really was at that point, especially given that we give *quite a lot* of warnings and indications as to what the site is supposed to be about.

Comment: The [leaky basement wall question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031674/how-can-i-fix-a-leaky-basement-wall-from-inside) from a couple of hours ago takes the cake :)

Comment: @Makoto New users do not come here with the *intent* of asking bad questions

Comment: @Robby - Yeah, that's too funny. It is unfortunate the opportunity to educate the user was not taken. Two opportunities were missed. First, explaining Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. Second, pointing him/her to [Home Improvement Stack Exchange](https://diy.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We are still working on getting the Ask a Question wizard into production. Current plan is to run and A/B test on it in September. Sorry it has taken so long.

One way to keep up to date on what we are doing each month is to check out the [Product team monthly updates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314164/354333) I post every month.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully something will be available before 2020. Please ensure whatever is added clearly and prominently states *"Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions"*. New users must be educated, and the site has traditionally done a bad job at the education part (*q.v.*).

Comment: @jww the test will go out with the copy largely as is in the prototype. Of course, once we have a baseline we can test other versions to see how they perform. Also, no disagreement with your last sentence. :/ We're working on more things than just the AaQ wizard to address that.

Comment: What about this wizard? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard

Comment: @xXNebulaNinjaXx That's the prototype referred to by the OP. We aren't directing any traffic to that at this point. It was put up for community feedback only.

Answer (score 1):

This [Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard) is very useful as it guides you through creating a Good question. I use to use it a lot but now as I am more knowledgeable it has become less useful to me. Althought it is still a very good tool for formatting.