# Require confirmation before allowing mostly-image or mostly-link posts

Tags: feature-request, new-users, hyperlinks, images, external-links

There are loads of new questions (mostly from new users) which primarily consist of a hyperlink to data or code or a picture of data or code.  For example: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52096324/1

I think the site could detect such questions by some simple metrics such as:

1. Does the user have low reputation?
2. Is there a link in the question?  Bonus points if it is a link to an image.
3. Is the number of words in the post relatively small?
4. Does the link text include keywords like "code" or "this code" or "my code"?
5. Would this be the first time we prompt this user about this?
6. Is this the user's first question, or were any of their recent questions
   closed for the reason that the content was not in the question itself?

Questions which score highly on the above could trigger a prompt when the user tries to submit.  The prompt might say:

> You may be submitting a question which is not answerable solely by reading the text within the question itself.  Questions which have textual content behind a link or in an image are strongly discouraged on this site.  If the links in your question are important and contain data or code, please copy the text (or at least an excerpt, if the whole is large) directly into the question.  Would you like to go back and edit your question before posting?
>
> `Yes` / `No`

Allowing new users to self-censor by informing them of the etiquette would reduce the time wasted and frustration experienced by other users who are looking for questions they can answer without visiting other sites or doing data entry from images of text.

Comment: Why does it have to be low reputation? And if you really feel like that must be, how low is low? (I have seen 2k+ users post questions like that) My point here is basicly to make it about the content (points 2,3 and 4) and not about the person (point 1).

Comment: @AndréKool: Perhaps the low-reputation metric (point 1) could be replaced or augmented by "Would this be the first time we prompt this user about this?" and/or "Is this the user's first question or do they have recent questions which were closed for the reason that the content was not in the question itself?"  I will add those points as 5 and 6 in the list.

Comment: @AndréKool If you have 20k, you most likely already know how to ask a good question, and any message we can show about this would be pointless and irritating. Or, in more technical terms, the ratio of false positives to true positives would tend to infinity as the user's reputation increases. There's a cutoff somewhere where it probably wouldn't make sense to show this any more. There may be a better measure than reputation for this, just don't ask me what that is.

Comment: @Dukeling I think the added points 5 and 6 cover that. Also how many _good_ questions have you seen that fall in the description being provided here? I really don't think looking at reputation (or any other metric) is needed here. I do agree that if you have proven you can ask, 3 for example, good questions you don't need another warning.

Comment: @AndréKool From my personal experience with filter-based classification tasks on this site, the reputation seems to be quite a useful signal. I find it very likely that it can be used effectively to reduce the number of false positives in this scenario, too.

Comment: The **"Ask a Question wizard'**, [which we're promised it'll be in production very soon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373036/4934172) might actually _(I feel optimistic about it)_ reduce the number of poorly written questions, which this particular problem falls into the category of. I'd say let's wait and see what the "Ask a Question wizard" produces before making any other changes to the "Ask a question" page.

Comment: "If you have 20k, you most likely already know how to ask a good question" - You'd be surprised!

Comment: @Dukeling Yesterday I saw a top-20-of-all-time user make two linked images in a new user's question inline. The two images were text-only screenshots of a homework assignment. I don't know, maybe he just doesn't agree that images of text are bad?

Comment: @m69 There can be a big difference between the quality of questions someone is willing to edit or answer and the quality of questions they're willing to ask. We don't really want people to "polish turds", as they say, but that's probably a different issue.

Comment: @JacobG. The surprisingly bad questions probably wouldn't be bad in *this specific* way, not to mention that such users are likely to believe they know better than some automated warning. It's also a trust thing - if you allow people to close, delete and single-handedly edit the posts of others, it probably also makes sense to trust them to know what a good question looks like. Not that this logic is really followed here - 40k+ reputation and I'm still not trusted to know when it makes sense to put "problem" in a title.