# Standardize the body of long questions

Tags: discussion, questions

Yesterday I was searching through some questions on Stack Overflow and I was thinking: could it be useful to standardize the way we write long questions?

I try, in my own questions, to set a standard body with the goal to provide a clearer question (I generally have a positive response to that).

I don't want to impose a specific formatting to others, it would be impossible and very bad, I am simply wondering if it's good having a sort of template ( obviously not decided by me ) when you set a question and if not why it could be so dangerous for us. Here's an example:

---

***Problem***

Here I write about the problem and what's the issue

***Documentation\research about this topic***

This voice saves me a lot of downvote because of the  "no research effort". It also has another purpose: in the future, the people will know why and how you arrived at this point, and what could help you.

***Expected Behaviour***

This field in my opinion is really important not only for the reader, but  for the writer too. It makes clearer  my task and what I want, sometimes it's hard describe in a few words exactly what you need.

***Codepen***

Here you will find the pen of your project.

***Code***

Interesting Code of the project here

***Consideration\Update***

In this field you will have all of your consideration or update about what you wrote

---

I don't want to impose this standard to everyone, obviously, but the positive effects that I have when doing it gives to me a lot of advantages when I post a question:

1. I'm forced to find documentation - and to read it -
2. I'm forced to understand what's my task
3. I'm forced to make a clear question and avoid the downvote syndrome
4. I prevent comments like "post your codepen" or similar

I believe something like that could really help the writer and the reader.

Comment: Wow, can i ask why these downvote ? just to understand .

Comment: Downvotes on meta usually indicate disagreement.

Comment: To the main point - I'm kind of in a hurry so I don't have the time to formulate this into an answer - the bigger smell here is "long question".  Questions shouldn't be overly verbose; they should be on-topic, on point, and narrowly focused.  Furthermore, I would discourage the use of Codepen over Stack Snippets since there's no guarantee that Codepen would be up when your question is up.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the downvotes, it's my first question on the meta. 
Yeah, but exactly what was a cons to use a sort of guide to ask a question ? I don't want to impose this kind of body, i'm a newbie, but why it will be so bad give some rails, maybe to the newbie when they ask the firsts question ?

Comment: I am glad you found a way to get your questions a good reception. It's far from the only way though, and forcing your specific way onto other users feels detrimental at best

Comment: There is a guide, help/how-to-ask and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ .

Comment: @user202729 That's it something i was talking about. Thanks to get point. Why strictly follow OR understand a guide like this could be so negative for our community ?

Comment: Because people don't think having a fixed *format* (writing style) is a good idea. The pages I linked guides you how to write the *content*, not the *format*.

Comment: The problem is 'strictly', at least in my mind. There are more than one way to ask a good question. Saying we have to strictly follow your template means we may miss out on some other great questions

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373036/17034

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for this link, the wizard is exactly what i'm talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems quite harsh to force a particular writing style. Sure, there are certain things that are expected, but other than that questions are pretty much freestyle. If it's missing something it'll be downvoted and/or closed. That's enough encouragement I would think.

Comment: No, i don't want to impose a style of writing, but why it could be so bad give a sort of rail for the question that you are askin ? The downvote it's pure fear for everyone, and a newbie it's always discouraged by this.

Comment: @Legeo When I was a newbie, I was not discouraged by downvotes. Downvotes that I received were my own fault, I hadn't read enough about what was expected of me or my questions. The downvotes, and user comments, made me reevaluate what I was doing and made me want to contribute even more in a meaningful way to StackOverflow.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Most new people DO get discouraged by downvotes though. Have you not seen all the blog posts of people claiming SO is full of rude people because their questions got downvoted?

Comment: @chevybow Yes, I have. But if people are going to get discouraged and leave for getting virtual downvotes for not following the rules of the website, can they really handle being on the site? They obviously want the rules to change to make it easier on them... But that is a discussion that has been brought up many times and this isn't really a good place to discuss it.